# "The duck pond": showcase of TikZ-drawn animals/ducks

Tags: tikz-pgf, fun, big-list, tikzducks, tikzlings

We have tons of nice TikZ-drawn pictures on this site. Among them some great pictures of animals like cfr's cat code. But they are distributed all over the site.

As we definitely miss a place to collect them, this post asks about nice examples of animals/pets drawn with TikZ. Especially those pictures about **ducks** are welcome.

For all of the duck friends, quack!

<sub>Please do not close this question too early (I know it's a bit out-of-concept here, but there are other well-known showcases).</sub>

Comment: duplicate: [How can we draw a duck (in order to create a tikzducks package and store it in CTAN)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/346695/123129)

Comment: @dexteritas No, this asks especially about ducks etc. drawn with the package (or TikZ in general), which look very creative. It's not about general designing a duck. See the chat for details.

Comment: I think this should be a community wiki big list question. Otherwise, it is just too broad. How will you choose between an answer drawing an earwig and one drawing a barn owl? I don't know where my cat code is, mind, and it probably doesn't match what I've got now. We also have donkeys and turkeys. Not sure what else.

Comment: I found (at least some of) the cat code. (I now have a library, but I think it is too much to post.)

Comment: I added the `big-list` tag so that it will show up in a search for questions of this kind. (Obviously roll back if you disagree.)

Comment: The duck package is growing and is going to be the biggest package in CTAN!!!!

Comment: Donkeys: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312199/i-need-a-tex-donkey

Comment: Fish: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361547/how-to-draw-a-fish

Comment: Some might say "Lenny" is an animal: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308600/how-to-include-a-lenny-face-in-a-latex-document-e-g-%cd%a1-%cd%9c%ca%96-%cd%a1

Comment: Not only animals, also fruits: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413389/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-of-an-apple-using-only-the-tikz-library

Answer (score 67):

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usepackage[prefix=]{xcolor-material}
\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{material}{%
{Red}{Blue}{Green}}
\tikzset{%
  half clip/.code={
    \clip (0, -256) rectangle (256, 256);
  },
  color/.code=\colorlet{fill color}{#1},
  color alias/.code args={#1 as #2}{\colorlet{#1}{#2}},
  colors alias/.style={color alias/.list/.expanded={#1}},
  execute/.code={#1},
  on left/.style={.. on left/.style={#1}},
  on right/.style={.. on right/.style={#1}},
  split/.style args={#1 and #2}{
    on left ={color alias=fill color as #1},
    on right={color alias=fill color as #2, half clip}
  }
}
\newcommand\reflect[2][]{%
\begin{scope}[#1]\foreach \side in {-1, 1}{\begin{scope}
\ifnum\side=-1 \tikzset{.. on left/.try}\else\tikzset{.. on right/.try}\fi
\begin{scope}[xscale=\side]#2\end{scope}
\end{scope}}\end{scope}}

\tikzset{%
cat/.pic={
\tikzset{x=3cm/5,y=3cm/5,shift={(0,-1/3)}}
\useasboundingbox (-1,-1) (1,2);
\fill [BlueGrey900] (0,-2)
  .. controls ++(180:3) and ++(0:5/4) .. (-2,0)
  arc (270:90:1/5)
  .. controls ++(0:2) and ++(180:11/4) .. (0,-2+2/5);
\foreach \i in {-1,1}
  \scoped[shift={(1/2*\i,9/4)}, rotate=45*\i]{
    \clip [overlay] (0, 5/9) ellipse [radius=8/9];
    \clip [overlay] (0,-5/9) ellipse [radius=8/9];
    \fill [BlueGrey900] ellipse [radius=1];
    \clip [overlay] (0, 7/9) ellipse [radius=10/11];
    \clip [overlay] (0,-7/9) ellipse [radius=10/11];
    \fill [Purple100] ellipse [radius=1];
  };
\fill [BlueGrey900] ellipse [x radius=3/4, y radius=2];
\fill [BlueGrey100] ellipse [x radius=1/3, y radius=1];
\fill [BlueGrey900]
  (0,15/8) ellipse [x radius=1, y radius=5/6]
  (0, 8/6) ellipse [x radius=1/2, y radius=1/2]
  {[shift={(-1/2,-2)}, rotate= 10]  ellipse [x radius=1/3, y radius=5/4]}
  {[shift={( 1/2,-2)}, rotate=-10] ellipse [x radius=1/3, y radius=5/4]};
\fill [BlueGrey500]
  (-1/9,11/8) ellipse [x radius=1/5, y radius=1/5]
  ( 1/9,11/8) ellipse [x radius=1/5, y radius=1/5];
\fill [Purple100]
  (0,12/8)     ellipse [x radius=1/10, y radius=1/5]
  (0,12/8+1/9) ellipse [x radius=1/5 , y radius=1/10];
\foreach \i in {-1,1}
  \scoped[shift={(1/2*\i,2)}, rotate=35*\i]{
    \clip [overlay] (0, 1/7) ellipse [radius=2/7];
    \clip [overlay] (0,-1/7) ellipse [radius=2/7];
    \fill [Yellow50] ellipse [radius=1];
  };
\scoped{
  \clip (-1,-2) rectangle ++(2,1);
  \fill [BlueGrey900] (0,-2) ellipse [radius=1/2];
  \fill [Grey100]
    (-1/2,-2) ellipse [x radius=1/3, y radius=1/4]
    ( 1/2,-2) ellipse [x radius=1/3, y radius=1/4];
};
\foreach \i in {-1,1}
  \foreach \j in {-1,0,1}
    \fill [Grey100, shift={(0,11/8)}, xscale=\i, rotate=\j*15,
      shift=(0:1/2)]
      ellipse [x radius=1/3, y radius=1/64];
},
duck/.pic={
\tikzset{x=3cm/100,y=3cm/100, shift={(-50,-50)}}
\fill [Amber800] (58,28)
  .. controls (56,28) and (55,27) .. (55,26)
  .. controls (55,25) and (56,16) .. (55,15)
  .. controls (54,14) and (54,12) .. (55,11)
  .. controls (56,10) and (66, 7) .. (68, 7)
  .. controls (70, 7) and (75,15) .. (73,15)
  .. controls (71,15) and (62,13) .. (60,15)
  .. controls (58,17) and (60,25) .. (60,26)
  .. controls (60,27) and (59,28) .. (58,28)
  -- cycle;
\fill [BlueGrey900] (1,57)
  .. controls ( 0,51) and ( 4,44) .. (10,42)
  .. controls (16,40) and (23,40) .. (24,47)
  -- cycle;
\begin{scope}
\clip [preaction={fill=LightGreen}] (74,96)
  .. controls (66,96) and (62,92) .. (60,88)
  .. controls (58,84) and (58,76) .. (61,68)
  -- (76,68)
  .. controls (72,72) and (74,74) .. (75,75)
  .. controls (82,75) and (88,76) .. (88,84)
  .. controls (88,92) and (82,96) .. (74,96)
  -- cycle;
\fill [Grey100] (57,68) rectangle +(20,4);
\end{scope}
\fill [BlueGrey50]
  (14,48)
  .. controls (14,34) and (32,21) .. (53,21)
  .. controls (55,21) and (57,21) .. (61,22)
  .. controls (81,27) and (92,36) .. (92,48)
  -- cycle;
\fill [Brown500] (61,68)
  .. controls (65,52) and (68,40) .. (61,22)
  .. controls (84,26) and (92,36) .. (92,48)
  .. controls (92,60) and (82,65) .. (76,68)
  -- cycle;
\fill [BlueGrey400] (56,64)
  .. controls (45,64) and (40,60) .. (32,56)
  .. controls (24,52) and ( 8,52) .. ( 8,48)
  .. controls (8, 44) and (24,36) .. (40,36)
  .. controls (56,36) and (68,44) .. (72,48)
  .. controls (76,52) and (72,56) .. (68,60)
  .. controls (64,64) and (60,64) .. (56,64)
  -- cycle;
\fill [Amber500] (88,84)
  .. controls (86,84) and ( 87,82) .. (86,81)
  .. controls (85,80) and ( 80,79) .. (83,76)
  .. controls (86,73) and ( 95,71) .. (97,71)
  .. controls (99,71) and (100,72) .. (99,73)
  .. controls (98,74) and ( 92,77) .. (91,80)
  .. controls (90,83) and ( 90,84) .. (88,84)
  -- cycle;
\fill (78,87)
  .. controls (77,85) and (80,82) .. (83,84)
  .. controls (83,87) and (80,88) .. (78,87)
  -- cycle;
\fill [Amber700] (50,25)
  .. controls (48,25) and (47,24) .. (47,23)
  .. controls (47,22) and (48,13) .. (47,12)
  .. controls (46,11) and (46, 9) .. (47, 8)
  .. controls (48, 7) and (58, 4) .. (60, 4)
  .. controls (62, 4) and (67,12) .. (65,12)
  .. controls (63,12) and (54,10) .. (52,12)
  .. controls (50,14) and (52,22) .. (52,23)
  .. controls (52,24) and (51,25) .. (50,25)
  -- cycle;},
horse/.pic={
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/448,y=3cm/448]
\fill [Brown200]
  (-128,128)
  to [bend left]  ++(-16,-128) to [bend right] ++( 32,  8)
  to [bend left]  ++(-48, -96) to [bend right] ++( 56,   8)
  to [bend left]  ++(-64, -96) to [bend right]   (  0, -96)
  (128,128)
  to [bend left] ++(32,-128) to [bend right] ++(-40,40)
  to [bend left] ++( 0, -96) to [bend right] ++(-64,96);
\reflect[
  on left ={color alias=ears as Brown600},
  on right={color alias=ears as Brown700},
  color 0/.style={ears}, color 1/.style={BlueGrey900}
]{
  \foreach \j in {0, 1}
  \fill [color \j]
  [shift={(96,120)}, rotate=45, scale=9/10-\j/3, xscale=9/10]
  (-72,0)
  .. controls ++( 90: 8) and ++(180:16) .. ( 0, 48)
  .. controls ++(  0:16) and ++( 90:12) .. (88,  0)
  .. controls ++(270:12) and ++(  0: 8) .. ( 0,-48)
  .. controls ++(180: 8) and ++(270: 8) .. cycle;
}
\reflect[split=Brown600 and Brown700]{%
  \fill [fill color] (-56,-160)
  .. controls ++( 90:176) and ++(270: 96) .. (-112,  64)
  arc (180:0: 112 and 112)
  .. controls ++(270: 96) and ++( 90:176) .. (  56,-160) -- cycle;
}
\reflect[split=Grey50 and Grey200]{%
  \fill [fill color] (0,-48)
    .. controls ++(135:48) and ++(225:48) .. (0,168)
    .. controls ++(315:48) and ++( 45:48) .. cycle;
}

\reflect[split=Brown50 and Brown100]{%
  \fill [fill color] (0,-164) ellipse [x radius=56, y radius=56];
}
\reflect[split=Brown200 and Brown300]{%
  \fill [fill color] (0,-164) ellipse [x radius=48, y radius=40];
}
\reflect[split=Brown50 and Brown100]{%
  \fill [fill color] (0,-144) ellipse [x radius=64, y radius=48];
}
\reflect[split=Brown50 and Brown100]{
  \fill [fill color]  (36, -128) ellipse [x radius=24, y radius=40];
  \fill [BlueGrey900] (36, -128) ellipse [x radius=12, y radius=24];
}
\fill [BlueGrey900]
  (-72, 64) ellipse [radius=20]
  ( 72, 64) ellipse [radius=20];
\fill [Brown200]
  (0,192)
  .. controls ++(180:64) and ++( 90:64) .. (-128, 64)
  .. controls ++( 60:16) and ++(180:16) .. ( -64,128)
   to [bend left]  (-80,88)
   to [bend right] (  0, 128)
   to [bend left]  (-16,  64)
   .. controls ++( 0:64) and ++(270:32) .. (96,144)
   .. controls ++(90:32) and ++(  0:64) .. cycle;
\end{scope}},
chimpanzee/.pic={
\tikzset{x=3cm/3.5,y=3cm/3.5, shift={(0,1/4)}}
\fill [BlueGrey700] (165:5/4 and 1) ellipse [radius=1/2];
\fill [Pink100]     (165:5/4 and 1) ellipse [radius=1/3];
\fill [BlueGrey700]
  (0,-1/2) ellipse [x radius=1, y radius=4/3]
  (0,   0) ellipse [x radius=4/3, y radius=1];
\scoped{
  \clip(0,-2) rectangle(9/5,1);
  \fill [BlueGrey900] (15:5/4 and 1) ellipse [radius=1/2];
  \fill [Pink200]     (15:5/4 and 1) ellipse [radius=1/3];
  \fill [BlueGrey900]
    (0,-1/2) ellipse [x radius=1, y radius=4/3]
    (0,   0) ellipse [x radius=4/3, y radius=1];
}
\fill [Pink100]            (  0,-2/3) ellipse [x radius=5/6, y radius=  1];
\fill [Pink100, xscale=-1] (1/2,   0) ellipse [x radius=3/5, y radius=2/3];
\fill [Pink100, xscale= 1] (1/2,   0) ellipse [x radius=3/5, y radius=2/3];
\scoped{
  \clip(0,-2) rectangle(9/5,1);
  \fill [Pink200]            (  0,-2/3) ellipse [x radius=5/6, y radius=  1];
  \fill [Pink200, xscale=-1] (1/2,   0) ellipse [x radius=3/5, y radius=2/3];
  \fill [Pink200, xscale= 1] (1/2,   0) ellipse [x radius=3/5, y radius=2/3];
}
\foreach \i in {-1,1}
  \fill [BlueGrey900, xscale=\i] (1/2,0) ellipse [radius=1/4];
\fill [Pink300]
  (-1/7,-2/3) ellipse [radius=1/9]
  ( 1/7,-2/3) ellipse [radius=1/9];
\fill [Pink300]
  (-1/2,-1) arc (180:360:1/2 and 1/8) arc (360:180:1/2 and 1/4);
},
shark/.pic={
\tikzset{x=3cm/22,y=3cm/22,shift={(-8,-11)}}
\fill [BlueGrey200]
  (2,16.75) -- ++(0.5,-1) -- ++(0.5,1) -- cycle
  (3,16.25) -- ++(0.5,-1) -- ++(0.5,1) -- cycle
  (1,17)    -- ++(0.5,-1) -- ++(0.5,1) -- cycle
  (2,15.5)  -- ++(-.5,-1) -- ++(1,0) -- cycle
  (3,15)    -- ++(-.5,-1) -- ++(1,0) -- cycle;
\fill [BlueGrey700] (6,12)
  .. controls (5,11) and (5,8)  .. (6,7)
  .. controls (7,8)  and (7,9)  .. (8,10)
  .. controls (8,11) and (7,12) .. (6,12)-- cycle;
\fill [BlueGrey500] (0,20)
  .. controls (0,19)  and (0,18)  .. (1,17)
  .. controls (3,16)  and (4,16)  .. (4,15)
  .. controls (4,14)  and (2,15)  .. (1,15)
  .. controls (2,13)  and (3,12)  .. (5,10)
  .. controls (7,8)   and (11,6)  .. (14,5)
  .. controls (14,3)  and (14,1)  .. (15,0)
  .. controls (15,2)  and (15,3)  .. (16,4)
  .. controls (17,5)  and (18,6)  .. (20,6)
  .. controls (19,7)  and (16,7)  .. (15,6)
  .. controls (14,10) and (11,15) .. (9,17)
  .. controls (7,19)  and (3,20)  .. (0,20) -- cycle;
\fill [BlueGrey100] (0,20)
  .. controls (0,19) and (0,18) .. (1,17)
  .. controls (3,16) and (4,16) .. (4,15)
  .. controls (4,14) and (2,15) .. (1,15)
  .. controls (2,13) and (3,12) .. (5,10)
  .. controls (7,8)  and (11,6) .. (14,5)
  .. controls (13,8) and (7,8)  .. (6,12)
  .. controls (5,16) and (2,19) .. (0,20) -- cycle;
\fill [BlueGrey500] (3,13)
  .. controls (2,12) and (2,9)  .. (3,8)
  .. controls (4,9)  and (4,10) .. (5,11)
  .. controls (5,12) and (4,13) .. (3,13) -- cycle;
\fill [BlueGrey500] (9,18)
  .. controls (8,18)  and (7.5,17.5) .. (7,17)
  .. controls (7,16)  and (9,14)     .. (10,14)
  .. controls (10,15) and (11,17)    .. (12,17)
  .. controls (11,18) and (10,18)    .. (9,18) -- cycle;
\fill [BlueGrey800] (6,17.5) circle [radius=0.5];
},
squid/.pic={
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/480,y=3cm/480]
\useasboundingbox (-256, -256) (256, 256);
\reflect[split={DeepOrange500 and DeepOrange700}]{
  \fill [fill color] (0,96) ellipse [x radius=96, y radius=128];
  \fill [fill color]
    (72,-16)
    .. controls ++(270:72) and ++(270:40) .. ++(108,  -16)
    .. controls ++( 90:64) and ++(270:64) .. ++(-40,128)
    .. controls ++( 90:32) and ++(270:32) .. ++( 40, 96)
    arc (180:0:4)
    .. controls ++(270: 32) and ++( 90: 32) .. ++(-24, -96)
    .. controls ++(270: 64) and ++( 90: 64) .. ++( 56,-128)
    .. controls ++(270:128) and ++(270:160) ..   (  0, -16);
  \fill [fill color]  (64, 16) circle [radius=48];
  \fill [Grey50]      (64, 16) circle [radius=32];
  \fill [BlueGrey900] (64, 16) circle [radius=12];
  \fill [fill color]  (-4, -20)
    .. controls ++(270:256) and ++(225: 64) .. (128,-192)
    arc (315:495:4)
    .. controls ++(210: 64) and ++(270:192) .. (48, -40);
}
\fill [DeepOrange900]
  (-40,-40) arc (180:360:40 and 16) arc (360:180:40 and 40);
\fill [DeepOrange300]
  (-32,108) circle [radius=16] (-40,160) circle [radius=12]
  (-20,196) circle [radius= 8]  ( 40,160) circle [radius=16]
  ( 64,120) circle [radius= 8]  ( 40,100) circle [radius=12];
\end{scope}
},
owl/.pic={
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/512,y=3cm/512]
\foreach \i in {-3,...,3}
  \fill [Brown900, shift={(0,128)}, rotate=-\i*13]
    (0,0) arc (90:450:48 and 144);
\foreach \i in {-1,...,1}
  \fill [Brown900, shift={(0,32)}, rotate=-\i*10]
    (0,0) arc (90:450:32 and 128);
\reflect[split={Brown700 and Brown800}]{
  \fill [fill color] (0,224)
  .. controls ++(180:96) and ++( 90:96) .. (-112,32)
  .. controls ++(270:96) and ++(180: 0) .. (0,-148)
  .. controls ++(  0: 0) and ++(270:96) .. ( 112,32)
  .. controls ++( 90:96) and ++(  0:96) .. cycle;
}
\reflect[
  on left ={colors alias={
    outer eye as Brown600, eyebrow as Brown800, chest as Brown100}},
  on right={colors alias={
    outer eye as Brown700, eyebrow as Brown900, chest as Brown200},
    half clip}]{
  \fill [outer eye]   (64, 128) circle [radius=80];
  \fill [Grey100]     (64, 128) circle [radius=40];
  \fill [BlueGrey900] (64, 128) circle [radius=20];
  \fill [eyebrow]  (0,112)
    .. controls ++( 90:128) and ++(270:64) .. (160,240)
    .. controls ++(270:112) and ++( 90:64) .. cycle;
  \fill [chest] 
    (0,-140)
    .. controls ++(135:32) and ++(270:32) .. (-64,-40)
    arc (180:0:64)
    .. controls ++(270:32) and ++( 45:32) .. cycle;
}
\reflect[
  on left ={colors alias={
    beak as Amber500, perch as BlueGrey800, foot as Brown600, 
    talon as Amber500}},
  on right={colors alias={
    beak as Amber700, perch as BlueGrey900, foot as Brown700, 
      talon as Amber700}, half clip}]{
  \fill [beak] (0,28)
    .. controls ++(135:32) and ++(270:16) .. (-32,64)
    arc (180:0:32)
    .. controls ++(270:16) and ++(45:32) .. cycle;
  \fill [perch]
    (-192,-128) arc (90:270:12) -- ++(384,0) arc (270:450:12) -- cycle;
  \tikzset{shift={(0, -128)}}
  \fill [foot]
    (3, 0) arc (180:0:36 and 24) -- cycle;
  \foreach \j in {-1,0,1}
    \scoped[shift={(40+20*\j,0)}]\fill [talon]
       (10,0) arc (0:180:10) -- (0,-16) -- cycle;
}
\end{scope}},
cow/.pic={
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/480,y=3cm/480]
\reflect[]{
\tikzset{shift={(32,140)}, rotate=-45}
  \fill [BlueGrey100] (0,0) arc (0:90:32 and 96) arc (90:0:96);
  \fill [BlueGrey200] (32,0) arc (0:90:64 and 96) arc (90:0:96);
}
\foreach \i in {-1, 1}\foreach \j in {0, 1}
\fill \ifnum\j=0 \ifnum \i=-1 [BlueGrey700] \else [BlueGrey800] \fi\else [BlueGrey900] \fi
  [xscale=\i, shift={(128,88)}, rotate=10, scale=1-\j/3]
  (-72,0)
  .. controls ++( 90: 8) and ++(180:16) .. ( 0, 48)
  .. controls ++(  0:16) and ++( 90:12) .. (88,  0)
  .. controls ++(270:12) and ++(  0: 8) .. ( 0,-48)
  .. controls ++(180: 8) and ++(270: 8) .. cycle;
\reflect[split={BlueGrey700 and BlueGrey800}]{%
  \fill [fill color] (-64,-160)
  .. controls ++( 90:144) and ++(270: 64) .. (-120,  64)
  arc (180:0: 120 and 112)
  .. controls ++(270: 64) and ++( 90:144) .. (  64,-160) -- cycle;
}
\reflect[split=Grey50 and Grey200]{%
  \fill [fill color](-64,-160)
    .. controls ++( 75:144) and ++(270: 64) .. (-16,  64)
    .. controls ++( 90: 32) and ++(180: 72) .. (  0, 168)
    .. controls ++(  0: 72) and ++( 90: 32) .. ( 16,  64)
    .. controls ++(270: 64) and ++(105:144) .. ( 64,-160) -- cycle;
}
\reflect[split=Pink100 and Pink200]{
  \fill [fill color] (0,-160) ellipse [x radius=64, y radius=56];
}
\fill [Pink300] (0, -160) ellipse [x radius=48, y radius=40];
\reflect[split=Pink100 and Pink200]{
  \fill [fill color] (0,-128) ellipse [x radius=80, y radius=56];
}
\fill [Pink300]
  (-32, -128) ellipse [radius=16]
  ( 32, -128) ellipse [radius=16];
\fill [BlueGrey900]
  (-64, 64) ellipse [radius=24]
  ( 64, 64) ellipse [radius=24];
\end{scope}
},
bee/.pic={
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/480,y=3cm/480, rotate=-45, shift=(270:48)]
\reflect[
  on left= {colors alias={body as BlueGrey800, stripes as Amber500}},
  on right={colors alias={body as BlueGrey900, stripes as Amber700}, half clip},
  lower wing/.style={fill=BlueGrey100}, upper wing/.style={fill=BlueGrey50}]{
  \fill [body] (0,-160)
    .. controls ++(120:64) and ++(270:64) .. (-88, -16)
    .. controls ++( 90:64) and ++(225:64) .. (  0, 128)
    .. controls ++(315:64) and ++( 90:64) .. ( 88, -16)
    .. controls ++(270:64) and ++( 60:64) .. cycle;
  \fill [body] (0,128) ellipse [x radius=80, y radius=56];
  \fill [body]
    (32,160) arc (180:90:64) -- ++(6,-6) coordinate [midway] (@)
    arc (90:180:64) -- cycle;
  \fill [body] (@) circle [radius=12];
  \begin{scope}
    \clip (0,-160)
      .. controls ++(120:64) and ++(270:64) .. (-88, -16)
      .. controls ++( 90:64) and ++(225:64) .. (  0, 128)
      .. controls ++(315:64) and ++( 90:64) .. ( 88, -16)
      .. controls ++(270:64) and ++( 60:64) .. cycle;
    \foreach \i in {0,...,2}
      \fill [stripes] (-256, -160 + \i*80) rectangle ++(512, 40);
  \end{scope}
  \foreach \s [count=\i from -1] in {lower wing, upper wing}
    \fill [style=\s, shift={(16,56)}, rotate=\i*32]
      (0,0)
      .. controls ++( 30:64) and ++(180:32) .. (128,56)
      arc (90:-90:56)
      .. controls ++(180:32) and ++(330:64) .. cycle;
}
\end{scope}},
monkey/.pic={%
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/448,y=3cm/448]
\useasboundingbox (-256, -256) (256, 256);
\reflect[
  on left ={ color alias/.list={skin as Brown700, ears as Pink100}},
  on right={ color alias/.list={skin as Brown900, ears as Pink200}, half clip }
]{
  \fill [skin] (140, 80) circle  [radius=56];
  \fill [ears] (140, 80) circle  [radius=32];
  \fill [skin] (  0, 72) ellipse [x radius=140, y radius=112];
  \fill [skin] (  0,-64) ellipse [x radius=172, y radius=112];
}
\reflect[
  on left ={color alias/.list={face as Pink100}},
  on right={color alias/.list={face as Pink200}, half clip}
  ]{
  \fill [face] (0,-64) ellipse [x radius=140, y radius=88];
  \fill [face] (40,64) ellipse [radius=64];
}
\reflect{
  \fill [BlueGrey900] (40, 64) circle [radius=24];
  \fill [Pink300]     (24,-16) circle [radius=16];
}
\fill [Pink300]
  (-96,-72) arc (180:360:96 and 32) arc (360:180:96 and 56);
\end{scope}},
donkey/.pic={
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/480,y=3cm/480]
\reflect[
  on left ={color alias=ears as BlueGrey500},
  on right={color alias=ears as BlueGrey700},
  outer ear/.style={fill=ears}, inner ear/.style={fill=BlueGrey900}
]{
  \foreach \s [count=\j from 0] in {outer ear, inner ear}
  \fill [style=\s]
  [shift={(88,120)}, rotate=75, scale=9/10-\j/3, xscale=3/2]
  (-72,0)
  .. controls ++( 90: 8) and ++(180:16) .. ( 0, 48)
  .. controls ++(  0:16) and ++( 90:12) .. (88,  0)
  .. controls ++(270:12) and ++(  0: 8) .. ( 0,-48)
  .. controls ++(180: 8) and ++(270: 8) .. cycle;
}
\reflect[split=BlueGrey500 and BlueGrey700]{%
  \fill [fill color] (-56,-160)
  .. controls ++( 90:112) and ++(270: 128) .. (-112,  48)
  arc (180:0:112 and 96)
  .. controls ++(270: 128) and ++( 90:112) .. (  56,-160) -- cycle;
}
\reflect[split=Grey500 and Grey600]{%
  \fill [fill color] (0,-164) ellipse [x radius=56, y radius=56];
}
\reflect[split=Grey700 and Grey800]{%
  \fill [fill color] (0,-164) ellipse [x radius=48, y radius=40];
}
\reflect[split=Grey500 and Grey600]{%
  \fill [fill color] (0,-144) ellipse [x radius=64, y radius=48];
  \fill [fill color]  (36, -128) ellipse [x radius=24, y radius=40];
  \fill [BlueGrey900] (36, -128) ellipse [x radius=12, y radius=24];
}
\fill [BlueGrey900]
  (-72, 40) ellipse [radius=20]
  ( 72, 40) ellipse [radius=20]
  (-8,160)
  to [bend left]  ++( 16, 32) to [bend right] ++( 16,-48)
  to [bend left]  ++( 16, 32) to [bend right] ++( 16,-48)
  to [bend right] ++(-32,-48) to [bend left]  ++(-16, 32)
  to [bend right] ++(-32,-32) to [bend left]  ++(  0, 32)
  to [bend right] ++(-32,-16) to [bend left]  ++( 16, 40)
  to [bend right] ++(-16, 32) to [bend left]  cycle;
\end{scope}},
chipmunk/.pic={
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/448,y=3cm/448]
\reflect[
  on left ={colors alias={fur as Brown500, ear as Pink100}},
  on right={colors alias={fur as Brown700, ear as Pink200}, half clip}
]{
  \begin{scope}[shift={(88,56)}, rotate=-10]
  \fill [fur] (0,0) arc (270:90:40 and 64) arc (90:-90:24 and 64);
  \fill [ear] (0,0) arc (270:90:32 and 48) arc (90:-90:16 and 48);
  \end{scope}
  \fill [fur] ( 0,  -8) ellipse [x radius=128, y radius=176];
  \fill [fur] (96,-72) ellipse [x radius= 96, y radius= 88];
}
\reflect[split={Grey300 and Grey400}]{
  \fill [fill color, shift={(72,-80)}, yscale=-1] (-96,0) 
  arc (180:270: 96 and 80) arc (270:360:112 and 88)
  to [bend left ] ++(-20,-8) 
  to [bend right] ++(12,32)
  to [bend left ] (30:96 and 80)
  arc (30:180:96 and 80) -- cycle;
  \fill [fill color] (56,16) [rotate=-5] ellipse [x radius=48, y radius=96];
}
\reflect[split={Brown100 and Brown200}]{
  \fill [Grey100] (4,-56) -- ++(0,-64) -- ++(24,0) -- ++(16,64) -- cycle;
  \fill [fill color] (0,-40) ellipse [x radius=80, y radius=48];
  \fill [fill color] (0,-48) ellipse [x radius=64, y radius=56];
}
\reflect[split={BlueGrey800 and BlueGrey900}]{
  \fill [fill color]
    (0,-56) 
    .. controls ++(  0:16) and ++(315:16) .. ( 36,0)
    .. controls ++(135:16) and ++( 45:16) .. (-36,0)
    .. controls ++(225:16) and ++(180:16) .. cycle;
  \fill [BlueGrey900] (56, 40) circle [radius=20];
}
\end{scope}},
ladybird/.pic={
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/512,y=3cm/512]
\tikzset{rotate=-45}
\reflect[split=BlueGrey800 and BlueGrey900]{
  \fill [fill color] (0,16) ellipse [x radius=96, y radius=144];
  \foreach \i [count=\n from 0] in {1,0,-1} \foreach \j in {0,1}
  \fill [fill color, shift=(40-\n*40:96 and 144), 
    rotate=30-\n*40, shift=(0:\j*60), 
    xscale=1-\j/3, yscale=1-\j/6, rotate=\i*\j*15]
    (0,4) -- ++(64,4) -- ++(0,-16) -- (0,-4) -- cycle;
}
\reflect[
  on left ={colors alias={spot as Grey800, wing as Red600}},
  on right={colors alias={spot as Grey900, wing as Red900}, half clip}
]{
\clip [preaction={fill=wing}] 
  (0,0 |- 45:128 and 144) -- (45:128 and 144) arc (45:-80:128 and 144);
\fill [spot] 
  ( 0, 96) circle [radius=32]
  (64, 64) circle [radius=16]
  (24,  0) circle [radius=24]
  (96, 16) circle [radius=12]
  (72,-64) circle [radius=20];
}
\reflect[
  on left ={colors alias={body as BlueGrey800, eye as Grey100}},
  on right={colors alias={body as BlueGrey900, eye as Grey200}, half clip}
]{
  \fill [body]
    (16,160) arc (180:90:64) -- ++(4,-4) coordinate [midway] (@)
    arc (90:180:64) -- cycle;
  \fill [body] (@) circle [radius=8];
  \clip [postaction={fill=body}] (80,128) 
    .. controls ++( 90:32) and ++(  0:32) .. (  0,192)
    .. controls ++(180:32) and ++( 90:32) .. (-80,128)
    .. controls ++(270:32) and ++(180:32) .. (  0,96)
    .. controls ++(  0:32) and ++(270:32) .. cycle;
  \fill [eye] (64,160) circle [radius=24];
}
\end{scope}},
dog/.pic={
\begin{scope}[x=3cm/480,y=3cm/480]
\useasboundingbox (-256, -256) (256, 256);
\reflect[split=Brown400 and Brown500]{
  \fill [fill color] (0,-64) ellipse [x radius=160, y radius=144];
  \fill [fill color] (0, 32) ellipse [x radius=128, y radius=112];
  \fill [fill color] (32,96)
  .. controls ++( 75:128) and ++(105:128) .. ++(192,  0)
  .. controls ++(285: 96) and ++(285: 96) .. ++(-80,-32)
  .. controls ++(105: 64) and ++( 75: 32) .. cycle;
}
\reflect[split={Grey100 and Grey200}]{
  \clip (0,-64) ellipse [x radius=160, y radius=144];
  \fill [fill color](0,-224) 
    .. controls ++(  0:64) and ++(270:64) .. ++(96,64)
    .. controls ++( 90:64) and ++(270:64) .. ++(-96,192)
    .. controls ++(270:64) and ++( 90:64) .. ++(-96,-192)
    .. controls ++(270:64) and ++(180:64) .. cycle;
}
\reflect[split={Pink100 and Pink200}]{
  \fill [fill color](0,-192) ellipse [x radius=28, y radius=32];
}
\reflect[split={BlueGrey800 and BlueGrey900}]{
  \fill [fill color](0,-144) 
    .. controls ++(  0:20) and ++(315:20) .. ++( 40,64)
    .. controls ++(135:20) and ++( 45:20) .. ++(-80, 0)
    .. controls ++(225:20) and ++(180:20) .. cycle;
  \fill [BlueGrey900] (56, 0) circle [radius=20];
  \fill [fill color] (-8,-112)
  -- ++(16,0) -- ++(0,-32) arc (180:360:24)
  arc (180:0:8) arc (360:180:40);
}
\end{scope}}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \animal [count=\i from 0, evaluate={\x=mod(\i,3)*5; \y=-floor(\i/3)*5;}]
  in {bee,cat,chimpanzee,chipmunk,cow,dog,donkey,duck,horse,ladybird,
      monkey,owl,shark,squid}{
\pgfmathrandomitem\materialColor{material}
\scoped[shift={(\x,\y)}]{
\fill [fill=\materialColor50] circle [radius=2];
\pic {\animal};
\node [below]at (0, -2) {\ttfamily\animal};
}}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I love the cat! The other animals too, but especially the cat!

Comment: That duck is a beauty! `:)`

Comment: Gorgeous! <3<3<3

Comment: The collection of icons would make a great package!

Comment: `ladybird` must be changed to `ladybug`.

Comment: This should be a package in CTAN.

Comment: We want a package!

Answer (score 52):

## Super TeX Duck

[[image] **Click here for the proper soundtrack** [image]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e9vrfEoc8_g)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \definecolor{superblue}{RGB}{28,82,156}
    \definecolor{superred}{RGB}{255,70,70}
    \duck[tshirt=superblue, bill=superred!40!brown, longhair=brown!70!red!80!black, cape=superred]
    \begin{scope}[xscale=0.01, yscale=-0.01, yshift=-7200, xshift=100]
        \path[fill=yellow!70!brown,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.280pt] 
        (19.1501,169.8999) .. controls (22.6621,185.2587) and (26.1741,200.6174) .. (29.6861,215.9762) .. controls (48.0064,202.1310) and (66.3266,188.2858) .. (84.6469,174.4406) .. controls (82.8840,171.7633) and (83.5049,166.2477) .. (79.3603,166.0137) .. controls (62.9510,164.8761) and (46.5417,163.7384) .. (30.1324,162.6008) .. controls (26.4716,165.0339) and (22.8108,167.4669) .. (19.1501,169.8999) -- cycle;
        \path[fill=superred,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.280pt] (30.3892,160.9069) .. controls (26.0015,163.8232) and (21.6137,166.7395) .. (17.2258,169.6556) .. controls (20.9503,185.9422) and (24.6743,202.2289) .. (28.3985,218.5155) .. controls (47.8256,203.8338) and (67.2526,189.1521) .. (86.6798,174.4706) .. controls (84.9008,171.2752) and (85.0408,167.0414) .. (82.1598,164.4961) .. controls (64.9030,163.2997) and (47.6461,162.1033) .. (30.3892,160.9069) -- cycle(29.8755,164.2947) .. controls (32.3633,163.8271) and (33.8198,165.0958) .. (31.6902,167.0082) .. controls (28.9838,171.6934) and (26.2774,176.3786) .. (23.5710,181.0638) .. controls (23.1554,177.2602) and (20.9993,173.6756) .. (21.6242,169.7787) .. controls (24.3746,167.9507) and (27.1251,166.1227) .. (29.8755,164.2947) -- cycle(76.7801,167.5466) .. controls (80.4604,166.5323) and (82.8325,171.9430) .. (81.6657,174.6950) .. controls (79.5366,177.3566) and (76.2910,178.8331) .. (73.7649,181.0982) .. controls (72.5330,181.7268) and (68.5768,185.8417) .. (70.3548,182.6185) .. controls (72.4966,177.5945) and (74.6383,172.5705) .. (76.7801,167.5466) -- cycle(39.6974,171.1477) .. controls (42.2965,171.3279) and (44.8956,171.5081) .. (47.4946,171.6883) .. controls (42.6972,180.8632) and (38.3661,190.3004) .. (33.2358,199.2896) .. controls (31.4746,202.1278) and (26.2131,201.6511) .. (27.3590,197.6295) .. controls (26.4820,193.7940) and (25.6049,189.9585) .. (24.7279,186.1229) .. controls (27.6766,181.5339) and (29.9816,176.4251) .. (33.7500,172.4331) .. controls (35.4497,171.2057) and (37.6550,170.8843) .. (39.6974,171.1477) -- cycle(55.7860,172.2631) .. controls (59.7578,172.8436) and (63.9574,172.1465) .. (67.7430,173.7593) .. controls (69.7610,177.0238) and (67.0777,180.4981) .. (66.1501,183.6430) .. controls (65.7213,187.4117) and (62.3605,189.8584) .. (59.5157,191.9592) .. controls (54.5406,195.4546) and (49.8125,199.2863) .. (44.9199,202.8973) .. controls (40.7783,202.6790) and (42.3696,197.6021) .. (43.9068,195.3714) .. controls (47.1153,189.7669) and (49.8067,183.8583) .. (52.8097,178.1329) .. controls (53.8018,176.1763) and (54.7939,174.2197) .. (55.7860,172.2631) -- cycle(29.0428,204.9923) .. controls (32.9677,205.3274) and (36.8926,205.6624) .. (40.8175,205.9975) .. controls (37.3725,207.7884) and (35.2074,211.6132) .. (31.2514,212.4846) .. controls (29.5641,210.3889) and (29.9644,207.4023) .. (29.0428,204.9923) -- cycle;
        \path[draw=black,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=4.00,line width=0.280pt] (30.3892,160.9069) .. controls (26.0015,163.8232) and (21.6137,166.7395) .. (17.2258,169.6556) .. controls (20.9503,185.9422) and (24.6743,202.2289) .. (28.3985,218.5155) .. controls (47.8256,203.8338) and (67.2526,189.1521) .. (86.6798,174.4706) .. controls (84.9999,171.3774) and (84.7278,166.4000) .. (82.1598,164.4961) .. controls (64.9030,163.2997) and (47.6461,162.1033) .. (30.3892,160.9069) -- cycle(29.8755,164.2947) .. controls (31.3768,164.5060) and (34.3214,163.9495) .. (32.2315,166.0711) .. controls (29.3447,171.0687) and (26.4578,176.0663) .. (23.5710,181.0638) .. controls (23.1458,177.3914) and (20.8902,172.9885) .. (21.6242,169.7787) .. controls (24.3746,167.9507) and (27.1251,166.1227) .. (29.8755,164.2947) -- cycle(76.7801,167.5466) .. controls (80.5319,166.6672) and (81.1722,170.3187) .. (82.2166,173.1606) .. controls (81.7613,176.2320) and (78.2235,177.2884) .. (76.2097,179.2506) .. controls (74.0365,180.8929) and (71.8633,182.5353) .. (69.6901,184.1776) .. controls (72.0534,178.6339) and (74.4168,173.0903) .. (76.7801,167.5466) -- cycle(39.6974,171.1477) .. controls (42.2965,171.3279) and (44.8956,171.5081) .. (47.4946,171.6883) .. controls (42.8362,180.7076) and (38.4557,189.8707) .. (33.6002,198.7877) .. controls (31.8670,201.5779) and (26.5743,202.6315) .. (27.4439,198.0007) .. controls (26.5386,194.0414) and (25.6332,190.0822) .. (24.7279,186.1229) .. controls (27.5616,181.6166) and (29.9448,176.7409) .. (33.4174,172.6921) .. controls (35.1561,171.2620) and (37.5122,170.8656) .. (39.6974,171.1477) -- cycle(55.7860,172.2631) .. controls (59.7604,172.8439) and (63.9586,172.1470) .. (67.7430,173.7593) .. controls (70.1370,177.4786) and (66.0436,181.5940) .. (65.7890,185.4784) .. controls (63.4243,190.1696) and (58.3136,192.3876) .. (54.4844,195.6692) .. controls (51.2962,198.0785) and (48.1080,200.4879) .. (44.9199,202.8973) .. controls (40.3492,202.7990) and (42.6086,196.8794) .. (44.3878,194.7420) .. controls (48.1872,187.2490) and (51.9866,179.7561) .. (55.7860,172.2631) -- cycle(29.0428,204.9923) .. controls (32.9677,205.3274) and (36.8926,205.6624) .. (40.8175,205.9975) .. controls (37.3797,207.7837) and (35.1608,211.6508) .. (31.2514,212.4846) .. controls (29.7442,210.8968) and (29.8959,207.3157) .. (29.0428,204.9923) -- cycle;
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

## Bat Duck

The symbol is borrowed from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47394/36296

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[body=black!60!gray, bill=orange!50!gray,cape=black!50!gray]
    \fill[black!60!gray,rotate=210, xshift=-60, yshift=-72] (0.40,1.20)--(0.50,0.90)--(0.70,1.20);
    \fill[black!60!gray,rotate=150, xshift=-15, yshift=-97] (0.40,1.20)--(0.50,0.90)--(0.70,1.20);
    %Following logo based on https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47394/36296
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.05, rotate=-5, xshift=270, yshift=400]
        \filldraw[fill=yellow] (0,0) ellipse (7.0 and 4.3);
    \draw[line width=0.1mm] (0,0) ellipse (6.5 and 3.8);
    \draw[line width=0.1mm,dashed,white] (0,0) ellipse (6.0 and 3.3);
        \pgfsetlinewidth{0.1mm}
        \pgfpathmoveto{\pgfpoint{0}{2.7cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.5cm}{2.7cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{3.25cm}}
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{1.2cm}{1.3cm}}{\pgfpoint{1.3cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{2cm}{1cm}}
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{3cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{3cm}{2.2cm}}{\pgfpoint{2cm}{3.1cm}}
        \pgfpatharcto{6cm}{3.3cm}{0}{0}{0}{\pgfpoint{3.2cm}{-2.8cm}}
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{4cm}{-2cm}}{\pgfpoint{4cm}{0}}{\pgfpoint{2.2cm}{-1.8cm}}
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{1.5cm}{-1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{-1cm}}{\pgfpoint{0cm}{-3.2cm}}
        \pgftransformcm{-1}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpointorigin} % This is the coordinate change from x to -x
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{1cm}{-1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1.5cm}{-1cm}}{\pgfpoint{2.2cm}{-1.8cm}}
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{4cm}{0cm}}{\pgfpoint{4cm}{-2cm}}{\pgfpoint{3.2cm}{-2.8cm}}
        \pgfpatharcto{6cm}{3.3cm}{0}{0}{1}{\pgfpoint{2cm}{3.1cm}}
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{3cm}{2.2cm}}{\pgfpoint{3cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{2cm}{1cm}}
        \pgfpathcurveto{\pgfpoint{1.3cm}{1cm}}{\pgfpoint{1.2cm}{1.3cm}}{\pgfpoint{1cm}{3.25cm}}
        \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpoint{0.5cm}{2.7cm}}
        \pgfpathclose
        \pgfusepath{fill,stroke}   
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Trekkie ducks

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\definecolor{unigold}{RGB}{203,157,52}
\definecolor{uniblue}{RGB}{46,114,167}
\definecolor{unired}{RGB}{177,49,34}

\definecolor{skink}{RGB}{245,206,193}
\definecolor{skins}{RGB}{255,222,151}
\definecolor{skinu}{RGB}{146,113,96}

\newcommand*{\insignia}{\node[rotate=15] at (wing) {\color{yellow!80!brown}\faLocationArrow};}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[tshirt=black!60!gray, jacket=unigold, body=skink, shorthair=brown!80!black, bill=skink!60!gray]
\insignia
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[tshirt=black!60!gray, jacket=uniblue, body=skins, shorthair=black!60!brown, bill=skins!60!gray]
\fill[skins,rotate=175, xshift=-46, yshift=-76] (0.45,1.20)--(0.50,0.80)--(0.65,1.20);
\insignia
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[tshirt=black!60!gray, jacket=unired, body=skinu, longhair=black!60!brown, bill=skinu!70!black]
\insignia
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Italy duck for CarLaTeX

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck
    \node[rotate=-20] at (2,1) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{bc-ditalie.mps}};
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Witch duck for cfr

"catcode" borrowed from [How can we draw a Christmas tree with decorations, using TikZ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39149/how-can-we-draw-a-christmas-tree-with-decorations-using-tikz/219610#219610)

```
\pdfminorversion=7
\RequirePackage[rgb,pdftex,dvipsnames,x11names]{xcolor}
\documentclass[tikz,border=5pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections,backgrounds}
\pgfdeclarelayer{foreground}
\pgfdeclarelayer{pen}
\pgfdeclarelayer{corff}
\pgfsetlayers{background,corff,main,pen,foreground}
\makeatletter
% adapted (simplified version) from tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarybackgrounds.code.tex
  \tikzset{%
    on foreground layer/.style={%
          execute at begin scope={%
            \pgfonlayer{foreground}%
            \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
            \tikzset{every on foreground layer/.try,#1}%
            \tikz@options%
          },
          execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
    },
    on pen layer/.style={
          execute at begin scope={%
            \pgfonlayer{pen}%
            \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
            \tikzset{every on pen layer/.try,#1}%
            \tikz@options%
          },
          execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
    },
    on corff layer/.style={
          execute at begin scope={%
            \pgfonlayer{corff}%
            \let\tikz@options=\pgfutil@empty%
            \tikzset{every on corff layer/.try,#1}%
            \tikz@options%
          },
          execute at end scope={\endpgfonlayer}
    },
    stripiau cwt/.style={draw=#1, very thin, shorten >=-5mm, shorten <=-5mm, double=#1, double distance=3.5mm},
    stripiau corff/.style={very thin, draw=#1, fill=#1},
    trwyn/.style={circle, yshift=1.25mm, minimum width=2.5mm, inner sep=0pt},
    llenwi cath/.style={fill=#1},
    llygaid/.style n args=2{inner color=#1, outer color=#2, ultra thick, draw},
    pics/cath b/.style n args=5{
      code={
        [ultra thick]
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{pen}% ref. workaround from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218166/ (Mark Wibrow)
          \begin{scope}[very thin]% [on pen layer={very thin}]
          \path [clip]
            (0,10mm) coordinate (pen1) arc (90:65:19mm and 20mm) coordinate [pos=.75] (pp1) coordinate (pen2)
              arc (65:45:19mm and 20mm)  coordinate (pen3)
              arc (45:-60:19mm and 20mm) coordinate [pos=.05] (pp4) coordinate [pos=.4] (pp5) coordinate [pos=.45] (pp8) coordinate [pos=.75] (pp9)  coordinate (pen8)
              arc (-60:-90:19mm and 20mm) coordinate (pen10)
              arc (-90:-120:19mm and 20mm) coordinate (pen9)
              arc (-120:-225:19mm and 20mm) coordinate [pos=.25] (pp10) coordinate [pos=.55] (pp11) coordinate [pos=.6] (pp6) coordinate [pos=.95] (pp7) coordinate (pen4)
              arc (-225:-245:19mm and 20mm) coordinate (pen5)
              arc (-245:-270:19mm and 20mm) coordinate [pos=.25] (pp2)
              ;
          \path [stripiau corff=#1]
            (pp2) [out=-45, in=95] to ($(pen1) - (0,10mm)$) coordinate (pp3) [out=85, in=-135] to (pp1) |- +(5mm,5mm) -| cycle
            (pp4) [out=-135, in=25] to +(-7.5mm,-4mm) [out=-25, in=115] to (pp5) -| +(5mm,5mm) |- cycle
            (pp7) [out=-45, in=155] to +(7.5mm,-4mm) [out=-155, in=65] to (pp6) -| +(-5mm,5mm) |- cycle
            (pp8) [out=-135, in=-25] to +(-17.5mm,0mm) [out=-45, in=115] to (pp9) -| +(5mm,5mm) |- cycle
            (pp11) [out=-45, in=-155] to +(17.5mm,0mm) [out=-135, in=65] to (pp10) -| +(-5mm,5mm) |- cycle
            ;
          \end{scope}
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \path
          (pen2) ++(4mm,7.5mm) coordinate (pen6)
          (pen5) ++(-4mm,7.5mm) coordinate (pen7);
        \path [rounded corners=1pt, llenwi cath=#2]
          (pen1) arc (90:65:19mm and 20mm)
            [out=80, in=-110] to (pen6) [out=-80, in=85] to
          (pen3) arc (45:-225:19mm and 20mm)
            [out=95, in=-100] to (pen7) [out=-70, in=100] to
          (pen5) arc (-245:-270:19mm and 20mm);
        \begin{scope}[on foreground layer={ultra thick}]
          \draw [rounded corners=1pt, ultra thick]
            (pen1) arc (90:65:19mm and 20mm)
              [out=80, in=-110] to (pen6) [out=-80, in=85] to
            (pen3) arc (45:-225:19mm and 20mm)
              [out=95, in=-100] to (pen7) [out=-70, in=100] to
            (pen5) arc (-245:-270:19mm and 20mm);
        \end{scope}
      \path [llenwi cath=#2]% corff
          (pp8) [out=35, in=100] to coordinate [pos=.075] (corff7) coordinate [pos=.1] (corff8) coordinate [pos=.2] (corff9) coordinate [pos=.225] (corff10) coordinate [pos=.325] (corff11) coordinate [pos=.35] (corff12) coordinate [pos=.45] (corff13) coordinate [pos=.475] (corff14) coordinate [pos=.575] (corff15) coordinate [pos=.6] (corff16) coordinate [pos=.7] (corff17) coordinate [pos=.725] (corff18) coordinate [pos=.825] (corff19) coordinate [pos=.86] (corff20) coordinate [pos=.96] (corff21) ++(75mm,-15mm) coordinate (corff5)
            [out=-80, in=-85] to coordinate [pos=.6] (corff6) coordinate [pos=.7] (corff22) coordinate [pos=.775] (corff23) coordinate [pos=.825] (corff24) coordinate [pos=.875] (corff27) coordinate [pos=.9] (corff25) coordinate [pos=.985] (corff26) (pen9);
         \begin{scope}[ultra thick]% stripiau'r corff
            \clip
              (pp8) [out=35, in=100] to (corff5)
                [out=-80, in=-85] to (pen9) |- cycle;
            \path [stripiau corff=#1]
              (pp8) [out=-95, in=65] to ++(7.5mm,-15mm) [out=45, in=-175] to (corff7)
              (corff8) [out=-85, in=50] to ++(7.5mm,-17.5mm) [out=45, in=-135] to (corff9)
              (corff10) [out=-90, in=60] to ++(5mm,-20mm) [out=50, in=-140] to (corff11)
              (corff12) [out=-100, in=55] to ++(2.5mm,-20mm) [out=50, in=-145] to (corff13)
              (corff14) [out=-110, in=50] to ++(0,-20mm) [out=40, in=-155] to (corff15)
              (corff16) [out=-115, in=40] to ++(-3.5mm,-18.5mm) [out=30, in=-170] to (corff17)
              (corff18) [out=-135, in=20] to ++(-7.5mm,-16.5mm) [out=10, in=-180] to (corff19)
              (corff20) [out=-170, in=-5] to ++(-10mm,-12.5mm) [out=-15, in=140] to (corff21)
              (corff26) [out=-45, in=-135] to ++(20mm,-1.5mm) [out=-115, in=45] to (corff25) -- +(-5mm,0) |- cycle
              (corff27) [out=40, in=-115] to ++(20mm,7.5mm) [out=-105, in=65] to (corff24) -- +(-5mm,0) |- cycle;
         \end{scope}
        \draw [ultra thick, name path=corff]
          (pp8) [out=35, in=100] to ++(75mm,-15mm)
            [out=-80, in=-85] to coordinate [pos=.6] (corff6) (pen9);
        \draw [ultra thick, llenwi cath=#2]% coesau
          (corff22) ++(17.5mm,12.5mm) coordinate (coes1)
          (corff23) ++(12.5mm,15mm) coordinate (coes2)
          (coes1) [out=-120, in=35] to (corff22) [out=-145, in=5] to ++(-20mm,-7.5mm) [out=-175, in=0] to ++(-5mm,0) arc (-90:90:-5mm and 3mm) coordinate (coes9) [out=0, in=-175] to ++(5mm,0) coordinate (coes11) [out=5, in=-145] to (corff23) [out=35, in=-100] to (coes2);
        \begin{pgfonlayer}{background}% ref. workaround from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218166/ (Mark Wibrow)
          \begin{scope}
            \draw [ultra thick, llenwi cath=#2]% coesau
              (corff23) [out=-145, in=5] to (coes11) [out=-175, in=0] to (coes9) arc (-90:90:-4mm and 2.5mm) [out=0, in=-145] to (corff24)
              ;
          \end{scope}
        \end{pgfonlayer}
        \path [llenwi cath=#2]% llenwi'r cwt
          (corff5) [out=-80, in=-15] to ($(corff6) + (0,-2.5mm)$) coordinate (cwt5)
            [out=165, in=-90] to ++(-5mm,5mm) coordinate (cwt6)
            [out=90, in=170] to ++(7.5mm,5mm) coordinate (cwt7)
            [out=-10, in=-95] to ($(corff5) + (-15mm,-2.5mm)$) coordinate (cwt8)
          ;
        \begin{scope}[ultra thick]% stripiau'r cwt
          \clip (corff5) [out=-80, in=-15] to
              coordinate [pos=.1] (cwt9)
              coordinate [pos=.15] (cwt10a)
              coordinate [pos=.25] (cwt11a)
              coordinate [pos=.345] (cwt12a)
              coordinate [pos=.44] (cwt13a)
              coordinate [pos=.53] (cwt14a)
              coordinate [pos=.62] (cwt15a)
              coordinate [pos=.71] (cwt16a)
              coordinate [pos=.805] (cwt17a)
              coordinate [pos=.9] (cwt18a)
              coordinate [pos=1] (cwt19a)
              (cwt5)
            [out=165, in=-90] to
              coordinate [pos=.45] (cwt20a)
              (cwt6)
            [out=90, in=170] to
              coordinate [pos=.65] (cwt20b)
              (cwt7)
            [out=-10, in=-95] to
              coordinate [pos=.025] (cwt19b)
              coordinate [pos=.125] (cwt18b)
              coordinate [pos=.225] (cwt17b)
              coordinate [pos=.325] (cwt16b)
              coordinate [pos=.425] (cwt15b)
              coordinate [pos=.525] (cwt14b)
              coordinate [pos=.625] (cwt13b)
              coordinate [pos=.725] (cwt12b)
              coordinate [pos=.825] (cwt11b)
              coordinate [pos=.925] (cwt10b)
              (cwt8)
            |- (corff21) -- cycle;
          \path [stripiau corff=#1]
            (corff5) [out=110, in=10] to ++(-7.5mm,-3.5mm) [out=0, in=120] to (cwt9);
          \path [llenwi cath=#1]
            (cwt20a) [out=80, in=-80] to (cwt20b) [out=170, in=90] to (cwt6) [out=-90, in=165] to cycle
            ;
          \foreach \i in {10,...,19}
            \draw [stripiau cwt=#1] (cwt\i a) [out=90, in=-60] to (cwt\i b);
        \end{scope}
        \draw [ultra thick, name path=cwt]
          (corff5) [out=-80, in=-15] to (cwt5)
            [out=165, in=-90] to (cwt6)
            [out=90, in=170] to (cwt7)
            [out=-10, in=-95] to (cwt8)
          ;
         \begin{scope}[on foreground layer={ultra thick}]
          \draw
            (pen10) -- ++(0,7.5mm) coordinate (ceg1)
              [out=-45, in=180] to +(5mm,-2.5mm) coordinate (ceg2)
              [out=0, in=-100] to +(2.5mm,3.5mm) coordinate (ceg3)
             ;
          \draw
            (ceg1)
              [out=-135, in=0] to +(-5mm,-2.5mm) coordinate (ceg4)
              [out=180, in=-80] to +(-2.5mm,3.5mm) coordinate (ceg5)
            ;
          \path (ceg1)
            node (trwyn1) [trwyn, anchor=west] {}
            node (trwyn2) [trwyn, anchor=east] {};
          \draw
            ($(trwyn1)!1/2!(trwyn2)$) coordinate (trwyn) [out=10,in=140] to +(25mm,7.5mm)
            (trwyn) [out=-10, in=120] to +(.5mm,-5mm)
            (trwyn) [out=-40, in=130] to +(-1.5mm,-5mm)
            ;
          \draw
            (trwyn) [out=170,in=40] to +(-25mm,7.5mm)
            (trwyn) [out=-170, in=60] to +(-.5mm,-5mm)
            (trwyn) [out=-140, in=50] to +(1.5mm,-5mm)
            ;
          \path (ceg1)
            node (trwyn1) [trwyn, draw, ball color=#5, anchor=west] {}
            node (trwyn2) [trwyn, draw, ball color=#5, anchor=east] {};
         \end{scope}
          \draw [llygaid={#3}{#4}]
          ({$(pen1)!2/5!(pen10)$} -| {$(pen8)!3/4!(pen4)$}) coordinate (llygad chwith)
            ++(-5mm,0) coordinate (llygad chwith 1) [out=20, in=180] to ++(6mm,2.5mm) coordinate (llygad chwith 2) [out=0, in=120] to ++(4mm,-2.5mm)
            [out=-120, in=0] to ++(-4mm,-2.5mm) [out=180, in=-20] to ++(-6mm,2.5mm)
          ;
          \draw [llygaid={#3}{#4}]
            ({$(pen1)!2/5!(pen10)$} -| {$(pen9)!3/4!(pen3)$}) coordinate (llygad de)
              ++(5mm,0) coordinate (llygad de 1) [out=160, in=0] to ++(-6mm,2.5mm) coordinate (llygad de 2) [out=180, in=40] to ++(-4mm,-2.5mm)
              [out=-40, in=180] to ++(4mm,-2.5mm) [out=0, in=-160] to ++(6mm,2.5mm)
          ;
          \fill [ball color=black] (llygad chwith 1 -| llygad chwith 2) circle (2.5mm);
          \fill [ball color=black] (llygad de 1 -| llygad de 2) circle (2.5mm);
          \begin{scope}[on foreground layer={ultra thick}]
            \draw [shorten >=1pt]
              ($(pen2)!7/10!(pen3)$) coordinate (clust1) [out=125, in=-80] to (pen6);
            \draw [shorten >=1pt]
              ($(pen5)!7/10!(pen4)$) coordinate (clust2) [out=55, in=-100] to (pen7);
          \end{scope}
          \begin{scope}% llenwi clust de
            \clip (clust1) [out=125, in=-80] to (pen6) [out=-110, in=80] to (pen2) |- cycle;
            \path [stripiau corff=#1, rounded corners=1pt]
              (clust1) [out=125, in=-80] to (pen6) [out=-110, in=80] to (pen2) arc (65:45:19mm and 20mm)
              ;
          \end{scope}
          \begin{scope}% llenwi clust chwith
            \clip (clust2) [out=55, in=-100] to (pen7) [out=-70, in=100] to (pen5) |- cycle;
            \path [stripiau corff=#1, rounded corners=1pt]
              (clust2) [out=55, in=-100] to (pen7) [out=-70, in=100] to (pen5) arc (-245:-225:19mm and 20mm)
              ;
          \end{scope}
          % dim yn ddefnyddiol ar hyn o bryd ond gobeithio bynnan nhw ar ôl iddyn nhw fix the bug!
          \coordinate (-pen) at (pen1);
          \coordinate (-clust chwith) at (pen7);
          \coordinate (-clust de) at (pen6);
        }
    },
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}
  \colorlet{lliw llygaid3}{Chartreuse1}
  \colorlet{lliw llygaid4}{Green4}
  \colorlet{lliw trwyn1}{LightPink2}
  \colorlet{cath5}{LavenderBlush3}
  \colorlet{cath6}{LavenderBlush4}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \path (-8,0) rectangle (10,21);
    \begin{scope}[transform canvas={scale=8},xshift=-30pt,yshift=-10pt]
        \duck[longhair=red!80!black,jacket=black!50!gray,magicwand]
            \fill[black!50!gray,rotate=-15] (0.44,2.13) ellipse (0.75 and 0.17);    
            \fill[black!50!gray,rotate=-15] (0.05,2.2)--(0.45,3.2)--(0.82,2.2);
      \end{scope}
    \pic {cath b={cath6}{cath5}{lliw llygaid3}{lliw llygaid4}{lliw trwyn1}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Queen duck

(code for including the crown by Ulrike Fischer)

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage[LSBC5,T1]{fontenc}

\definecolor{skin}{RGB}{225,219,206}
\definecolor{bill}{RGB}{170,123,154}
\definecolor{dress}{RGB}{184,209,206}
\definecolor{crown}{RGB}{90,76,183}

\usepackage{chessfss}
\setboardfontencoding{LSBC5}%
\setboardfontcolors{%
    whiteonwhitepiecemask=crown,
    whitepiece=gray!60!white
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[body=skin,bill=bill,jacket=dress,tshirt=teal!20!dress,shorthair=gray!60!white]
    \node[rotate=-10] at (1.03,2.45) {\scalebox{2.1}{\WhiteKingOnWhite}}; 
    \fill[gray!60!white,rotate=-10] (0.6,2.18) ellipse (0.38 and 0.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Farm animals

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\definecolor{skin}{RGB}{161,140,126}
\definecolor{bill}{RGB}{238,212,191}
\definecolor{hair}{RGB}{89,72,72}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[body=skin,bill=bill,shorthair=hair]
    \node[skin,rotate=45,scale=3] at (1.7,1.55) {\textsf{s}};
    \fill[hair,rotate=45] (2.4,0.13) ellipse (0.15 and 0.07);
    \begin{scope}[yshift=1]
        \clip (0.3,2.2) circle (0.4);
    \fill[skin] (0.9,2.3) circle (0.4);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=1]
        \clip (0.3,2.2) circle (0.35);
    \fill[bill] (0.9,2.3) circle (0.35);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (1.5,2.05) circle (0.4);
    \fill[skin] (1.0,2.35) circle (0.4);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (1.5,2.05) circle (0.35);
    \fill[bill] (1.0,2.35) circle (0.35);
  \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[body=bill!30!white,bill=bill,shorthair=bill]
    \fill[bill] (1.85,1.35) circle (0.2);
    \begin{scope}[yshift=1]
        \clip (0.3,2.2) circle (0.4);
    \fill[bill] (0.9,2.3) circle (0.4);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[yshift=1]
        \clip (0.3,2.2) circle (0.35);
    \fill[bill!30!white] (0.9,2.3) circle (0.35);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (1.5,2.05) circle (0.4);
    \fill[bill] (1.0,2.35) circle (0.4);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (1.5,2.05) circle (0.35);
    \fill[bill!30!white] (1.0,2.35) circle (0.35);
  \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}   

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[body=red!20!white,bill=red!40!white,shorthair=red!30!white]
    \node[red!20!white,rotate=25,scale=3] at (1.7,1.51) {\textsf{s}};
    \begin{scope}[yshift=-1]
        \clip (0.3,2.2) circle (0.35);
    \fill[red!30!white] (0.9,2.3) circle (0.35);
  \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (1.5,2.02) circle (0.35);
    \fill[red!30!white] (1.0,2.35) circle (0.35);
  \end{scope}  
\end{tikzpicture}       

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The male super duck has some interesting hair...

Comment: @TeXnician "add more hair styles" is on my list of future enhancements - for now this is the best I could do.

Comment: @TeXnician I will do after someone else post an answer (this question should not be a one-duck show :)

Comment: your enthusiasm for ducks is next level! fantastic :)

Comment: No no... correct soundtrack is here!  ;) 
 https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e8yx4k4tzqE

Comment: Wouldn't a cat from the Halloween version be more appropriate for a witch?

Comment: @TeXnician Seem good from the duck's point of view.

Comment: @TeXnician Proportions of rubber ducks to other objects are tricky - while cats sizes have a narrow range of possible sizes ducks can be any size: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Rubber_Duck_(8374802487).jpg

Comment: @cfr nahhh, I like your cat :)

Comment: TeX cats can vary in size, although it will not work if you try to make them too small or too large. (But the same is true of TeX ducks.)

Comment: @cfr If ones does not know how to do it, scaling tex cats/ducks can be rather tricky. First I tried using `scale=...` and failed miserably as this did not effect the line widths. Fortunately  `transform canvas={scale=...}` seems to work better.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I have a later version and can just say `\pic {cath={maint=20mm}};` for a double-sized cat, but the dimensions are still hard-coded in the version you've got. (I didn't think anybody else would try to use the code ....)

Comment: @cfr Just to make sure my last comment came out right: This is explicitly no critique of your code, just a general problem I face with tikz and also in my own ducks. You have absolutely nothing to apologise for and I am very glad you shared your code with this community!

Comment: I certainly hope all this is going to be integrated into the package :-)

Comment: @Daniel Some of this is already in the package :) The other things are on the agenda, but are delayed due to various difficulties. For example the ears of the bat duck refuse to look good in a possible combination with hair ...

Answer (score 33):

Now this is community wiki, I feel comfortable starting a list of links. Please add links to this list if you're aware of other questions featuring animals on site.

- [I need a TeX-donkey](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/312199/i-need-a-tex-donkey)

  [image: donkey] [image: another donkey] [image: yet another donkey] [image: still another donkey]
- [Draw a turkey, a pumpkin pie, or any other object traditionally associated with Thanksgiving](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279788/draw-a-turkey-a-pumpkin-pie-or-any-other-object-traditionally-associated-with)

  [image: turkey] [image: another turkey] [image: cat]
- [How can we draw a duck (in order to create a tikzducks package and store it in CTAN)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/346695/how-can-we-draw-a-duck-in-order-to-create-a-tikzducks-package-and-store-it-in-c?s=9|0.5673)

  [image: ducks]
- [How to draw a fish?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/361547/how-to-draw-a-fish)

  [image: fish] [image: another fish] [image: metafish] [image: yet another (non-meta) fish]
- [animal icons in Tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/273361/animal-icons-in-tikz) (code for tortoises)
  [image: tortoises in grey]
  [image: tortoises in colour]
- [Cute (child-friendly) document in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63732/cute-child-friendly-document-in-latex) (the original duck code: by the ducks, for the ducks)

  [image: duck]
- [How to get a pigeon to illustrate the pigeonhole principle?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324506/how-to-get-a-pigeon-to-illustrate-the-pigeonhole-principle) (and doves)

  [image: pigeons & doves]
- [How to make a simple drawing of an apple using only the tikz library?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/413389/how-to-make-a-simple-drawing-of-an-apple-using-only-the-tikz-library?noredirect=1&lq=1) (shark hiding in the fruit bowl)

  [image: shark]

We mustn't forget that human beings are also members of the animal kingdom.

- [Custom "human" shape for tikz](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84275/custom-human-shape-for-tikz)

  [image: people] [image: another person] [image: triangle people] [image: outlined people] [image: yet more people]
- [Theory of Mind Type Figure](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/198378/theory-of-mind-type-figure)

  [image: heads of people]
- [Drawing a torso with a head (using \draw)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/338151/drawing-a-torso-with-a-head-using-draw)

  [image: torsos]
- [tikz path use draw area](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/299929/tikz-path-use-draw-area) (snow people)

  [image: snow people]
- [How do we Draw a Bird in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46798)

  [image: birds]

Off-site:

- http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/parameterised-pig/ (pigs)

  [image: pigs]

Comment: @CarLaTeX Do you know any additions? I'm sure I'm forgetting some. I only found the tortoises by accident, even though I drew them :).

Comment: @CarLaTeX Please add links as appropriate - this is community wiki, after all :-).

Comment: @CarLaTeX I think I edited at the same time - sorry.

Comment: The birds at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/46983 are nice too.  But they may not get along with your cats.

Comment: @Thérèse Please add them. I promise not to edit for a bit so I don't overwrite you.

Comment: Being humans also part from animal kingdom, a reference to `tikzpeople` is missing. Examples: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338455/1952, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/338434/1952

Comment: @Ignasi Do please add: it is community wiki and I really did make specially careful not to overwrite Thérèse's edits after managing to overwrite CarLaTeX's. I promise not to edit for a bit to avoid overwriting yours, too.

Answer (score 31):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-vehicle,tikzducks}

\def\V{\rput(1,1.5){\psscalebox{-2 2}{\tikz{\duck[alien=red]}}}}
\def\F{cos(x)/2+x/3}

\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {0,0.2,...,8}{
\begin{pspicture}(-1,0)(11,5)   
    \psplot{-1}{11}{\F}
    \psVehicle[vehicle=\SelfDefinedVehicle,ownvehicle=\V,showSlope=false,frontwheel=\SpokesWheelB,backwheel=\SpokesWheelA,rB=1,rF=0.7,d=3]{.5}{\i}{\F}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Feature: The tube valve of the front wheel is rolling without "sleeping".

Comment: OH MY THIS IS FANTASTIC

Comment: *To the duckmobile!*

Comment: Have you had another account on the tex exchange? Your style reminds me of another user....

Comment: I thought so :) good to see you again

Comment: @cmhughes: Your another relevant comment is [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/158668/nice-scientific-pictures-show-off/158741#comment373521_158741).

Answer (score 28):

## Soccer ducks

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\definecolor{verdep}{RGB}{0,100,55}
\definecolor{bluinter}{RGB}{0,102,170}
\definecolor{rossocagliari}{RGB}{149,20,38}
\definecolor{blucagliari}{RGB}{23,52,84}

\newcommand{\aggiusto}{\clip (-.4,-.2) rectangle (2.4,2.5);
    \fill[cyan!30] (-.4,-.2) rectangle (2.4,2.5);}

\makeatletter

% no more needed, now included in TikZducks package
%\newcommand*{\stripes}[1][]{\tikzset{/stripes/.cd,#1}\stripes@draw}

\tikzset{
    /stripes/.cd,
    color/.code=\def\stripes@color{#1},
    distance/.code=\def\stripes@distance{#1},
    width/.code=\def\stripes@width{#1},
    height/.code=\def\stripes@height{#1},
    initialx/.code=\def\stripes@initialx{#1},
    initialy/.code=\def\stripes@initialy{#1},
    rotate/.code=\def\stripes@rotate{#1},
    shifttype/.code=\def\stripes@shifttype{#1},
    % set defaults
    color=black,
    distance=.3,
    width=.15cm,
    height=2cm,
    initialx=.2,
    initialy=1,
    rotate=0,
    shifttype=xshift,
}

\def\stripes@draw{
    \begin{scope}
        \clip \duckpathjacket;
        \foreach \shifta in {0,\stripes@distance,...,2.4} 
            {\node[rectangle, fill=\stripes@color, draw=\stripes@color, inner sep=0pt, 
                text width=\stripes@width,
                minimum height=\stripes@height, 
                \stripes@shifttype=\shifta cm,
                rotate=\stripes@rotate] at (\stripes@initialx,\stripes@initialy) {};}
    \end{scope}
}
\makeatother

\tikzset{%
    pics/soccerball/.style args={#1/#2/#3}{code={%
            \draw[#3,fill=#1] (0,0) circle [radius=.9];
            \begin{scope}
                \clip (0,0) circle [radius=.9];
                \foreach \i in {-.4,.4}
                \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill=#2,minimum height=3.5ex] at (\i,.4) {};
                \foreach \i in {-.8,0,.8} 
                \node[regular polygon,regular polygon sides=6,fill=#2,minimum height=3.5ex] at (\i,-.4) {};
            \end{scope}
    }}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \aggiusto
    \duck[tshirt=black]
    \stripes[color=bluinter]
    \pic[scale=.4, transform shape] at (.2,.3) {soccerball={bluinter/black/white}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Inter duck}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \aggiusto
    \duck[tshirt=black]
    \stripes[color=white]
    \pic[scale=.4, transform shape] at (.2,.3) {soccerball={white/black/black}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Juve duck}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \aggiusto
    \duck[tshirt=black]
    \stripes[color=red]
    \pic[scale=.4, transform shape] at (.2,.3) {soccerball={red/black/black}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Milan duck}
\end{subfigure}
\vspace{4ex}

\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \aggiusto
    \duck[tshirt=green]
    \stripes 
    \pic[scale=.4, transform shape] at (.2,.3) {soccerball={green/black/black}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{M\"{o}nchengladbach duck}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
\begin{tikzpicture} 
    \aggiusto
    \duck[tshirt=green,jacket=verdep] 
    \pic[scale=.4, transform shape] at (.2,.3) {soccerball={verdep/green/green}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Palmeiras duck}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \aggiusto
    \duck[tshirt=orange,jacket=orange] 
    \stripes[color=yellow, shifttype=yshift, width=5cm, height=.15cm, distance=.3,
        initialx=0, initialy=0] 
    \pic[scale=.4, transform shape] at (.2,.3) {soccerball={yellow/orange/black}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Van Duck's team}
\end{subfigure}
\vspace{4ex}

\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \aggiusto
    \duck[tshirt=white, jacket=blucagliari] 
    \stripes[color=rossocagliari, width=.64cm, distance=3]
    \pic[scale=.4, transform shape] at (.2,.3) {soccerball={blucagliari/rossocagliari/white}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Cagliari duck}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \aggiusto
    \duck[tshirt=blue, jacket=blue] 
    \stripes[color=white, initialy=.65, height=.6cm, width=3cm]
    \stripes[color=red, initialy=.7, height=.1cm, width=3cm]
    \stripes[color=black, initialy=.6, height=.1cm, width=3cm]
    \pic[scale=.4, transform shape] at (.2,.3) {soccerball={blue/white/black}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Sampdoria duck}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture} 
    \aggiusto
    \duck[tshirt=blue, jacket=blue] 
    \stripes[color=white, rotate=45, width=.25cm, height=1.2cm, 
        initialx=.12, initialy=.9, distance=3]
    \stripes[color=white, rotate=-70, width=.25cm, height=1.8cm,  
        initialx=1.26, initialy=.81, distance=3]
    \pic[scale=.4, transform shape] at (.2,.3) {soccerball={white/blue/black}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Brescia duck}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Soccer ducks}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Cook duck

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.symbols}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\newcommand{\aggiusto}{\clip (-.6,-.2) rectangle (2.4,3);}

\tikzset{%
    pics/rollingpin/.style args={#1/#2}{code={%
        \draw[#2, fill=#1, rotate=45] (.06,.71) -- ++(0,.15) to[out=90, in=90] ++(.07,0) -- ++(0,-.15);
        \draw[#2, fill=#1, rotate=45] (0,0) to[bend right] ++(.2,0) -- ++(0,.7) to[bend right] ++(-.2,0) -- cycle;
        \draw[#2, rotate=45] (0,0) to[bend left] ++(.2,0);
        \draw[#2, fill=#1, rotate=-135] (-.13,0) -- ++(0,.15) to[out=90, in=90] ++(.07,0) -- ++(0,-.15);
    }},
    pics/cookcap/.style args={#1/#2}{code={%
        \node[cloud,draw=#2,fill=#1, rotate=-30, text width=.4cm, aspect=2, inner ysep=0pt] at (.4,.45) {};
        \draw[#2,fill=#1, rotate=-30] (-.1,.38) -- (-.1,0) to[bend right] ++(.42,0) -- ++(0,.38);
    }},
}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \aggiusto
    \duck[book=\scalebox{0.35}{\bfseries\hspace{2pt}Pizzas},bookcolour=red]
    \pic at (.1,.7) {rollingpin={brown/black}};
    \pic at (head) {cookcap={white/cyan}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{Cook duck\\ (no pineapple pizza on the menu)}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!!!!!!

Comment: The football duck would be a very nice addition to the package. May I add something based on your code to the package (of course mentioning you as the contributor of the football duck)? Otherwise I would just add a link in the documentation and point to this answer.

Comment: @samcarter I'll be honored if you use some of my code in the `tikzducks` package! Please do it!

Comment: Take as much time as you want, ducks can wait to play football :) As for the stripes, I was trying to test if maybe slightly bent stripes would work. What would you think of using `\duckpathjacket` for the stripes, this way one could use a tshirt in one of the team colour underneath and have the effect of a collar?

Comment: That's where 100% percent of my `xkeyval` knowledge come from :) Without egreg (the duck hero!) the ducks would be pretty boring and not customisable.

Comment: @samcarter See my renewed answer. I'm not completely satisfied with the way to choose the horizontal/vertical stripes, but I'm sure you'll improve it!

Comment: Fantastic new ducks! The Professor now has is own team?

Comment: @samcarter Of course! But it doesn't play in the major league :):):)

Comment: I will have a closer look at the code sometime next week (when I have more time) and have a look how to integrate it into the package.

Comment: They cannot play in the duck league and the major league at the same time :)

Comment: @samcarter A practical use for soccer ducks: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/440501/1952

Comment: soccer ducks - I get "Command \stripes already defined. ...[]{\tikzset{/stripes/.cd,#1}\stripes@draw}"

Comment: @InLaw I have corrected. The command is now included in the package.

Answer (score 28):

[Maxwell's demon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxwell%27s_demon).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.2cm,line cap=round]
  \draw (0,0) circle (1);
  % Eyes
  \filldraw (180:.2) ellipse (.1 and .2);
  \filldraw (180:.65) ellipse (.1 and .2);
  % Mouth
  \draw (200:1) to[out=-20,in=220] (-50:.3);
  % Feet
  \draw (250:1) -- ++(250:.5) -- ++(160:.5);
  \draw (300:1) -- ++(300:.5) -- ++(200:.5);
  % Horns
  \filldraw (120:1) to[out=160,in=-90] (120:2) to[out=-120,in=120] (160:1) arc(160:120:1) -- cycle;
  \filldraw (70:.9) to[out=20,in=-90] (60:2) to[out=-60,in=40] (20:.8) to[bend left] (70:.9) -- cycle;
  % Tail
  \draw (-30:1) to[bend right] (-10:2);
  \filldraw (-10:2) to[bend left] (-5:1.9) to[bend right] (10:2.5) to[bend left] (-12:2.2) to[bend left] (-10:2) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting interpretation of an animal/pet/duck ;)

Comment: +1, but now I wonder what Maxwell's Zombies would look like!

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/212525/demonic-correspondence-best-practices-when-defining-devils-in-tikz ;)

Comment: Very beautiful, though I'm thinking the mouth is just a tad high...maybe `\draw (203:1) to[out=-20,in=220] (-55:.36);`??

Answer (score 27):

Cat code demonstration for those fortunate enough to be uninitiated.

[image: cat codes]

```
\documentclass[border=11pt,x11names,svgnames,dvipsnames]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cathod,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pic {cath eistedd={enw=bob}};
    \pic at (60mm,0)  {cath eistedd bathodyn={enw=rusty, bathodyn={\textsf{\textbf{\Huge R}}}, lliw=DarkOrange1, llenwi=DarkOrange1, stripiau=OrangeRed3, ceg=Chocolate4, llygaid mewnol=Chartreuse, llygaid allanol=DarkGoldenrod1, trwyn=Orange1, llygaid amlinellol=DarkOrange4, trwyn amlinellol=DarkOrange4, wisgers/.style={DarkOrange4}}};
  \pic [below right=-20mm and 0pt of bob] {cath gorwedd={enw=dilly, llenwi=white, stripiau=gray, llygaid mewnol=cyan, llygaid allanol=blue!50!cyan, trwyn=pink}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

One or more of these cats have appeared in

- https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219610/ (with a non-library version of code for the third cat)
- [Draw a turkey, a pumpkin pie, or any other object traditionally associated with Thanksgiving](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279788/draw-a-turkey-a-pumpkin-pie-or-any-other-object-traditionally-associated-with/279870#279870) (with a non-library version of code for the third cat, which I always seem to end up colouring similarly, for some reason)
- [TUG Membership: Names for 2015](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5905/tug-membership-names-for-2015/5919?s=2|0.0345#5919) (non-library version of code for the second cat, with a TUG theme)
- [Seasonal Challenge (Contributions from TeXing Dead Welcome)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/336768/seasonal-challenge-contributions-from-texing-dead-welcome?s=6|0.0916) (spooky cats)
- [Ideas for a physical (non-PDF-digital) Bookmark](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329558/ideas-for-a-physical-non-pdf-digital-bookmark/329656?s=16|0.0339#329656) (cats on bookmarks)
- [The duck giveaway 2016, seasonal edition](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6914/the-duck-giveaway-2016-seasonal-edition/6936#6936) (cats-supporting ducks in the TSPCD)
- https://tex.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A39222+cath (...)

Comment: Your code is not compilable, we miss the `cathod` tikzlibrary.

Comment: @CarLaTeX As I said above, I don't know where the code here is. I used the one on my machine, but that one won't work for anybody else. More importantly, I think it exceeds the character limit.

Comment: @CarLaTeX Isn't there a 30,000 character limit? Otherwise, I could post mine. (It will only work for me as is, but it would not be hard to make it work elsewhere. Or I could post it with the thing it depends on, but, again, it is going to exceed the total limit.) Really, it could be reduced and would be better for stream-lining, but that would take a while ;).

Comment: @CarLaTeX An earlier version of the code for one of them is at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219610/ and should work generally. (It is not a library yet and there is much less of it.)

Comment: @CarLaTeX I found the other place - it's on *meta* ....

Comment: I love your cats! The way the whisker is bend they look really friendly!

Comment: @samcarter Thanks! Your ducks are much more professional, but I'm quite fond of my cats, I must admit ;). The code is a bit buggy. At least, the library version I'm using is. If I'm not careful, two cats get mixed up. I guess it might work for Schrödinger's cats :-). I need a way to 'flatten' each cat after it is drawn ....

Comment: If there’s `tikzducks` and `tikzpeople`, CTAN needs a `tikzcats` package.  Please, please, please, on behalf of all crazy cat-ladies!

Comment: @Thérèse The trouble is that if you put one in front of another in the wrong way, they interact like an uncollapsed Schrödinger's cats. (I know he only had the one cat and you do need two to generate interference with mine, but, then, mine are all at the macro level.) I don't know how to 'flatten' them. The only idea I've had is to draw the cat in a box and then use the box. But I'm not sure how to do this without nesting `tikzpicture`s.

Comment: I did look at @samcarter's code to see how he avoids duck interactions, but he's not drawing them the way I'm drawing the cats.

Comment: @Thérèse And my code is much less professional than the others'. You can't dress my cats up or arm them with swords or have them play soccer or ... anything. They lie there or sit there and that's it! (Maybe I could argue that's because their cats?)

Comment: @Thérèse I'll think about it .... I'll see. Might take a little while, though.

Comment: @cfr As I don't really know what I am actually doing (I don't know anything about `tikz`),  it is actually not surprising that I draw them in another way then someone who knows tikz :) I agree with Therese, a cat package would be lovely!

Comment: @samcarter Liar!

Comment: Yes, they just lie or sit there because they’re cats.  Beautiful cats who need no dressing up.  ;-)

Comment: @cfr - superficially convincing explanation, but what about active cat codes?

Comment: @MichaelPalmer Aha! An argument against my needing to make a package of it - thank you :-).

Answer (score 26):

(continuation from the previous answer due to lengths constraints)

## Zorro duck

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[cape=black,hat=black]
    \begin{scope}
        \clip (0.90,1.50) ellipse (0.50 and 0.625);
        \fill[black,rotate=-15] (-0.1,1.59) rectangle (1.3,1.88);
    \end{scope}
    \fill[white!85!yellow, rotate=-20] (0.23,1.7675) ellipse (0.0893 and 0.125);
    \fill[black, rotate=-20] (0.26,1.7575) ellipse (0.0357 and 0.0714);
    \fill[white!85!yellow, rotate=-20] (-0.06,1.74) ellipse (0.0786 and 0.1143);
    \fill[black, rotate=-20] (-0.03,1.73) ellipse (0.0286 and 0.0643);
    \node[rotate=-5] at (0.4,0.7) {\fontfamily{pzc}\selectfont zzz};
    \fill[black,rotate=24] (0.1,0.21) rectangle (1.1,0.23);
    \fill[black,rotate=24] (1.2,0.22) ellipse (0.15 and 0.03);
    \fill[black,rotate=24] (1.08,0.22) ellipse (0.03 and 0.15);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Frosty duck

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[blue!15!white] (0,0) rectangle (2.2,2.5);
    \duck[body=white,eye=white,tophat=black]
    \draw[very thick] (0.9,0.3) -- (1.2,1) (1.2,1) -- (1,1.3) (1.2,1) -- (1.3,1.3) (1.2,1) -- (1.5,1.4) (1.32,1.15) -- (1.6,1.3) ;
    \fill[black] (0.53,0.75) circle (0.05);
    \fill[black] (0.5,0.6) circle (0.05);
    \fill[black] (0.47,0.45) circle (0.05);
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Happy Christmas to all of you!

(The following code needs the development version of the `tikzducks` https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks/blob/master/tikzducks.sty )

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\definecolor{fskin}{RGB}{161,140,126}%
\definecolor{fbill}{RGB}{238,212,191}%
\definecolor{fhair}{RGB}{89,72,72}%
\definecolor{crown}{RGB}{255,220,123}
\definecolor{skin}{RGB}{255,215,146}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\fill[blue!20!white] (-1.5,-0.7) rectangle (19.2,7.2);

% sheep #1
\begin{scope}[xscale=-0.6,yscale=0.6]
    \duck[body=white!80!brown, bill=white!60!brown, sheep]
\end{scope}

% donkey
\begin{scope}[xscale=-0.8,yscale=0.8,xshift=-70,yshift=10]
    \duck[body=fskin,bill=fbill,shorthair=fhair,bunny,inear=fbill]
    \node[fskin,rotate=150,scale=3] at (1.75,1.59) {\reflectbox{\small\textsf{s}}};
    \fill[fhair,rotate=45] (2.65,0.05) ellipse (0.15 and 0.07); 
\end{scope}  

% building
\begin{scope}[scale=0.038,yshift=300,xshift=-1500]
    \path[draw=brown!50!black,line width=6.000pt] (129.0546,0.7705) .. controls (122.1203,65.4904) and (113.6451,66.6461) .. (113.6451,66.6461) -- (113.6451,66.6461) (91.3013,59.3266) .. controls (92.3303,59.5764) and (93.3577,59.8332) .. (94.3832,60.0971) .. controls (139.4171,71.6830) and (180.7789,97.1457) .. (211.4045,132.1365) .. controls (242.2399,97.1582) and (283.7423,71.7125) .. (328.9019,60.0971) .. controls (329.9275,59.8333) and (330.9548,59.5765) .. (331.9838,59.3266) (294.2305,0.7705) .. controls (301.1648,65.4904) and (309.6400,66.6461) .. (309.6400,66.6461) -- (309.6400,66.6461);
\end{scope}

% Mary
\begin{scope}[xscale=-1,yshift=15,xshift=-150]
    \duck[tshirt=blue!30!gray,longhair,body=skin]
\end{scope} 

% crib
\begin{scope}[scale=0.25,xshift=650,yshift=145]
    \duck
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[scale=0.038,yshift=1200,xshift=4100]
    \path[draw=brown,line join=miter,line cap=butt,miter limit=10.00,line width=1.275pt] (5.6693,-15.5908) -- (22.6775,-28.3468)(22.6775,-15.5908) -- (5.6693,-28.3468);
    \path[fill=brown,nonzero rule] (0.0000,-5.6693) -- (28.3468,-5.6693) -- (22.6775,-17.0082) -- (5.6693,-17.0082);
\end{scope}

% Joseph
\begin{scope}[xscale=1,yshift=10,xshift=190]
    \duck[tshirt=red!30!brown,shorthair=brown!50!black,body=skin]
\end{scope} 

% sheep #2
\begin{scope}[xscale=0.6,yscale=0.6,yshift=10,xshift=455]
    \duck[body=white!80!brown, bill=white!60!brown, sheep]
\end{scope}

% Magi #1
\begin{scope}[yshift=-20,xshift=360]
    \duck[tshirt=green!10!brown,shorthair=brown,crown=crown,body=skin,jacket=green!30!brown,buttons=green!10!brown!80!black,cake]
\end{scope}

% Magi #2   
\begin{scope}[yshift=0,xshift=420]
    \duck[tshirt=red!30!brown,shorthair=brown!45!black,crown=crown!70!yellow,body=skin!30!brown!80!black,bill=orange!50!brown!65!black,jacket=red!30!brown!80!black,beard,buttons=brown!45!black,pizza]
\end{scope}

% Magi #3   
\begin{scope}[yshift=-10,xshift=480]
    \duck[tshirt=teal!30!brown,shorthair=brown!65!red,crown=crown!80!yellow,body=skin!90!white,jacket=teal!30!brown!80!black,buttons=white!50!brown,wine]
\end{scope} 

% comet
\begin{scope}[xscale=0.03,yscale=-0.03,yshift=-7000,xshift=-2000]
    \path[fill=crown!80!yellow] (238.7832,10.0000) -- (234.8516,26.2656) -- (218.1582,27.4336) -- (230.2793,38.9707) -- (222.9434,54.0117) -- (238.9961,49.2832) -- (248.3535,63.1562) -- (252.2852,46.8906) -- (268.9785,45.7227) -- (261.8457,38.9336) .. controls (270.2556,38.8419) and (278.6830,40.2309) .. (286.5977,43.0781) .. controls (298.4672,47.3482) and (309.1501,54.8655) .. (317.1777,64.5957) .. controls (319.3767,67.2610) and (321.3804,70.0887) .. (323.1660,73.0469) -- (316.1934,49.2793) -- (325.9688,44.4219) .. controls (323.7865,42.0532) and (321.4179,39.8563) .. (318.8926,37.8574) .. controls (309.1476,30.1439) and (297.0216,25.4810) .. (284.6191,24.6797) .. controls (276.2092,24.1363) and (267.6990,25.3763) .. (259.7676,28.2207) -- (264.1934,19.1445) -- (248.1406,23.8730) -- (238.7832,10.0000) -- cycle;
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Astro duck

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[glasses];

\begin{scope}[scale=0.7,yshift=90,xshift=10]
\fill[gray] (-2.9466,0.3003) -- (-3.1837,-0.4402) -- (-2.7744,-0.5708) -- (-2.7308,-0.4348) -- (-1.8176,-0.7262) -- (-2.6937,-2.5325) -- (-2.4891,-2.6173) -- (-1.7766,-1.1484) -- (-1.7910,-2.8438) -- (-1.5698,-2.8326) -- (-1.5560,-1.2208) -- (-0.8785,-2.6173) -- (-0.6739,-2.5325) -- (-1.5011,-0.8272) -- (-0.3532,-1.1935) -- (-0.3096,-1.0574) -- (-0.1147,-1.1196) -- (-0.0566,-0.9382) -- (-0.2516,-0.8760) -- (-0.2032,-0.7249) -- (-2.5809,0.0337) -- (-2.5373,0.1697) -- (-2.9466,0.3003) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Harlequin duck

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[harlequin,jacket=red,stripes={\stripes[color=blue, width=0.46, distance=3]}]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Arara

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzducks}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
\duck[parrot,bill=gray!80!black]
\shade[left color=cyan!90!blue,right color=blue!70!black] \duckpathwing;
\shade[bottom color=yellow!70!brown, top color=green!40!teal] \duckpathcrazyhair;
\shade[bottom color=yellow!70!brown, top color=cyan!90!blue]
        (1.56,1.76) .. controls (1.60,1.74) and (1.62,1.72) .. (1.63,1.69) .. controls (1.67,1.63) and (1.71,1.55) .. (1.69,1.47) .. controls (1.67,1.40) and (1.65,1.31) .. (1.66,1.23) .. controls (1.66,1.20) and (1.69,1.19) .. (1.72,1.18) .. controls (1.77,1.17) and (1.82,1.19) .. (1.87,1.20) .. controls (1.94,1.22) and (2.01,1.24) .. (2.08,1.27) .. controls (2.13,1.30) and (2.16,1.35) .. (2.16,1.40) .. controls (2.15,1.45) and (2.14,1.50) .. (2.11,1.54) .. controls (2.08,1.55) and (2.09,1.50) .. (2.08,1.49) .. controls (2.06,1.42) and (2.01,1.37) .. (1.95,1.35) .. controls (1.93,1.33) and (1.97,1.36) .. (1.97,1.38) .. controls (1.99,1.44) and (1.97,1.50) .. (1.94,1.55) .. controls (1.91,1.60) and (1.89,1.64) .. (1.85,1.67) .. controls (1.83,1.68) and (1.85,1.63) .. (1.85,1.61) .. controls (1.87,1.55) and (1.87,1.48) .. (1.83,1.43) .. controls (1.83,1.50) and (1.80,1.56) .. (1.76,1.61) .. controls (1.72,1.67) and (1.67,1.71) .. (1.61,1.75) .. controls (1.61,1.76) and (1.60,1.76) .. (1.60,1.76) -- cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

## Don Camillo and Peppone

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=-1]
    \selectcolormodel{gray}
    \duck[tshirt=white,jacket=brown!50!black,buttons=gray,hat=brown!50!black,tie=brown,stripes={
     \stripes[rotate=0,width=0.02,color=gray,distance=0.1]}]
     \begin{scope}[xshift=62,yshift=1,xscale=-1]
\fill[gray!50!black] (1.8158,1.4731) .. controls (1.5890,1.5312) and (1.5142,1.3598) .. (1.2808,1.3608) .. controls (1.1720,1.2048) and (1.9376,1.4368) .. (1.8158,1.4731) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}   


\begin{tikzpicture}
    \selectcolormodel{gray}
    \duck[tshirt=black,buttons=gray,laughing]
 \fill[black, start angle=0, end angle=150, radius=0.5] (1.4,1.75) arc;
   \fill[black,rotate=-15] (0.44,2.1) ellipse (0.6 and 0.1);
    \fill[white,rotate=-12] (0.32,1.) rectangle (0.43,1.15);
\end{tikzpicture}   


\end{document}
```

[image]

## Zebra

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[brown!50!white] (0,0) rectangle (3,2.6);
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-6]
            \clip[rotate=-5] (0.68,2.38) ellipse (0.3 and 0.4);
            \fill[gray!10!white,rotate=-5] (0.28,2.26) ellipse (0.3 and 0.4);
        \end{scope}
    \duck[body=gray!10!white,stripes={\stripes[distance=0.25,width=0.125,rotate=0,initialx=0.06]},horsetail,mohican=black]
        \begin{scope}[yshift=-5,xshift=1]
            \clip[rotate=-5] (0.68,2.38) ellipse (0.3 and 0.4);
            \fill[gray!10!white,rotate=-5] (1.06,2.2) ellipse (0.3 and 0.4);
        \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You should say the reason of the triple z :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX "DPCorro" sounds bad...

Comment: @CarLaTeX the zzz is left for interpretation by the beholder

Comment: @TeXnician What about Dorro?

Comment: Oooh the snow duck! <3 <3 <3

Answer (score 25):

Ducks love pizza, swimming and a little diving:[image]

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% uncomment \def\export{} below to export animation
%% to multipage PDF a.pdf and run
%% 
%%  convert -density 300 -delay 4 -loop 0 -alpha remove a.pdf b.gif
%%
%% to get an animated GIF b.gif at 100/4 = 25 frames per s
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%\def\export{}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\ifdefined\export
  \documentclass[export]{standalone}
\else
  \documentclass{standalone}
\fi  

\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{xsavebox}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts,calc}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%% adjustable parameter: frame number; 
%% enlarge for smoothness 
\newcommand\framefac{2} % times 72
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand\DuckSong[1]{\ifcase#1
All%
\or
my%
\or
little%
\or
ducklings,%
\or
Swimming%
\or
in%
\or
the%
\or
lake,%
\or
Heads%
\or
dunk%
\or
in%
\or
the%
\or
water,%
\or
As%
\or
little%
\or
tails%
\or
do%
\or
shake.%
\fi%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\let\intEval\int_eval:n
\let\intMod\int_mod:nn
\let\intComp\int_compare:nTF
\let\intCase\int_case:nnF
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\xsbox{Duck}{\tikz{\duck}}%
\xsbox{CarlaDuck}{\tikz{\duck[pizza,squareglasses=brown!50!black,longhair=black!70!brown]}}%
\xsbox{Boat}{\tikz{%
  \filldraw[fill=white,line width=0.1pt] (0.6,0.71)--(1,1.2)--(1.4,0.71)--(1,0.6)--cycle;
  \node[scale=0.1,rotate=10,anchor=south east] at (2.3,0.9) {\includegraphics{pauloTransp}};
  \filldraw[fill=white,line width=0.1pt] (0,0)--(2,0)--(2.4,1)--(1,0.6)--(-0.4,1)--cycle;}}%
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay, loop, controls=false]{25}
  \multiframe{\intEval{72*\framefac}}{iX=0+1}{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[use as bounding box,white!90!blue] (-1,-1) rectangle (7.2,3);
    \node[scale=2,anchor=center,rotate=6*cos(360/(72*\framefac-1)*\iX)] at ({-3.8+\iX*13.8/(72*\framefac-1)},{0.9+0.1*sin(360/(72*\framefac-1)*\iX)}){\theBoat};
    \fill[blue!60!black] plot[variable=\x,domain=-1:7.2,samples=82] ({\x},{0.1+0.3*sin(100*(\x-0.5*\iX/10/\framefac))})--(7.2,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,0);
    \fill[blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=-1:7.2,samples=82] ({\x},{0.05+0.3*sin(100*(\x-\iX/10/\framefac))})--(7.2,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,0);
    \node[rotate=27.63*cos(100*(2.2-\iX/10/\framefac))] (duck) at ({2.2},{0.95+0.3*sin(100*(2.2-\iX/10/\framefac))}){\theCarlaDuck};
    \node[ellipse callout,text width=3.5em,align=center,draw,anchor=east,callout absolute pointer={($(duck.west)+(0.3,0.1)$)},fill=white] (song)
      at ($(duck)+(-1,1)$) {\makebox[0pt][c]{\DuckSong{\intEval{(\iX-\intMod{\iX}{4*\framefac})/(4*\framefac)}}}};
    \foreach \duckscal/\duckoff in {0.3/0,0.25/1,0.2/2,0.15/3,0.12/4}  
      \node[
        rotate=\intComp{\duckoff<4}{0}{\intComp{\iX<36*\framefac}{0}{
        \intCase{\iX}{{36*\framefac}{22.5}{36*\framefac+1}{45}{36*\framefac+2}{67.5}{72*\framefac-3}{67.5}{72*\framefac-2}{45}{72*\framefac-1}{22.5}}{90}}}
        +27.63*cos(100*(3.6+\duckoff*0.7-\iX/10/\framefac)),scale=\duckscal,anchor=south] at ({3.6+\duckoff*0.7},{0.3*sin(100*(3.6+\duckoff*0.7-\iX/10/\framefac))-0.04}){\theDuck};
    \fill[blue] plot[variable=\x,domain=-1:7.2,samples=82] ({\x},{0.3*sin(100*(\x-\iX/10/\framefac))})--(7.2,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,0);
    \fill[blue!60!white] plot[variable=\x,domain=-1:7.2,samples=82] ({\x},{0.3*sin(100*(\x-2*\iX/10/\framefac))-0.2})--(7.2,-1)--(-1,-1)--(-1,0);
    \draw[white,line width=1pt] (-1,-1) rectangle (7.2,3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
  }
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

For compilation, you need [↗Paulo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBuO6.png), the Captain. Save it as `pauloTransp.png` in the current directory.

By default, the code compiles to a single-page PDF with an embedded animation. It requires Acrobat Reader for viewing. For producing an animated GIF, as shown above, follow instructions in the code.

Comment: Maybe this technique could solve https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/445193/36296 Could you please have a look?

Comment: This is a bit more involved, I am afraid. I always feared this question would come up some day. Perhaps some internal modifications of `animate` are required.

Comment: ...... Ok, done.

Answer (score 21):

> The following examples part of the [Ti*k*Zlings](https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings), now also available as package on CTAN: https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzlings

## Teddy bear:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%  mitte: x=0.925

% Body %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[brown!70!black] (0.925,0.75) ellipse (0.55 and 0.65); 
\fill[brown!50!white] (0.925,0.7) ellipse (0.35 and 0.4); 

% Feet %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[brown!70!black] (1.35,0.3) circle (0.28); 
\fill[brown!70!black] (0.50,0.3) circle (0.28);
\fill[brown!50!white] (1.35,0.3) circle (0.17); 
\fill[brown!50!white] (0.50,0.3) circle (0.17);

% Ears %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[brown!70!black] (1.30,1.95) circle (0.15);
\fill[brown!70!black] (0.55,1.95) circle (0.15);
\fill[brown!50!white] (1.30,1.95) circle (0.1);
\fill[brown!50!white] (0.55,1.95) circle (0.1);

% Head %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[brown!70!black] (0.925,1.55) circle (0.5); 

% Muzzle %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[brown!50!white] (0.925,1.4) ellipse (0.28 and 0.2); 
\fill[brown!70!white!80!red] (0.925,1.5) ellipse (0.15 and 0.08); 

% Eyes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[brown!30!black] (0.77,1.7) circle (0.05); 
\fill[brown!30!black] (1.08,1.7) circle (0.05); 

% Mouth %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\draw[brown!30!black] (1.07,1.38) arc [start angle=-20, end angle=-160, radius=0.16];

% Arms %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[brown!70!black,rotate around={-50:(1.45,0.9)}] (1.45,0.9) ellipse (0.35 and 0.15);
\fill[brown!70!black,rotate around={50:(0.4,0.9)}] (0.4,0.9) ellipse (0.35 and 0.15);

\duck[invisible,tophat]

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Pingu:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\makeatletter
\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\penguin}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}%
        \tikzset{/penguin/.cd,#1}%
        \penguin@draw%
    \end{scope}%
}

\newif\ifpenguin@name
\newif\ifpenguin@threeD

\tikzset{
  %
  % Pass unknown keys on to tikz
  %
  /penguin/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
  /penguin/.cd,
  name/.code         = \penguin@nametrue \def\penguin@name{#1},
  %
  % body
  %
  body/.code         = \def\penguin@body{#1},
  body               = black,
  belly/.code        = \def\penguin@belly{#1},
  belly              = white!95!black,
  feet/.code         = \def\penguin@feet{#1},
  feet               = yellow!50!orange,
  bill/.code         = \def\penguin@bill{#1},
  bill               = orange,  
  eye/.code          = \def\penguin@eye{#1},
  eye                = white!95!black,
  pupil/.code        = \def\penguin@pupil{#1},
    pupil              = black, 
    %
    % options
    %
    3D/.code                 = \penguin@threeDtrue, 
}

\def\penguin@draw{%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% minimal bounding box size 
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\path (0.06,0.15) rectangle (1.8,2.13);
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% 
% switch between 2D and 3D, from
% https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/45991801#45991801
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ifpenguin@threeD
    \def\penguin@part@draw##1{\shade[ball color=##1]}
\else
    \def\penguin@part@draw##1{\fill[##1]}
\fi
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Body parts
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Arms %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\penguin@part@draw{\penguin@body,rotate around={-50:(1.5,1.2)}} (1.5,1.2) ellipse (0.38 and 0.1);
\penguin@part@draw{\penguin@body,rotate around={50:(0.35,1.2)}} (0.35,1.2) ellipse (0.38 and 0.1);  
%
% Body %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\penguin@part@draw{\penguin@body} (1.52,0.92) .. controls (1.52,0.26) and (1.28,0.18) .. (0.95,0.18) .. controls (0.61,0.18) and (0.32,0.26) .. (0.32,0.92) .. controls (0.32,1.58) and (0.59,2.11) .. (0.92,2.11) .. controls (1.25,2.11) and (1.52,1.58) .. (1.52,0.92) -- cycle;
%
% Belly %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\penguin@part@draw{\penguin@belly} (0.925,0.6) ellipse (0.48 and 0.35);
%
% Feet %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[xshift=4]
    \penguin@part@draw{\penguin@feet} (0.5319,0.3941) .. controls (0.5138,0.4505) and (0.4245,0.6014) .. (0.3275,0.6533) .. controls (0.2261,0.7075) and (0.2214,0.6369) .. (0.2428,0.5960) .. controls (0.2712,0.5416) and (0.2237,0.5302) .. (0.1952,0.5384) .. controls (0.1022,0.5653) and (0.0298,0.5169) .. (0.1131,0.4340) .. controls (0.1335,0.4137) and (0.2100,0.3557) .. (0.0982,0.3492) .. controls (0.0250,0.3450) and (0.0181,0.2680) .. (0.1082,0.2445) .. controls (0.2000,0.2206) and (0.3206,0.2043) .. (0.4571,0.2096) .. controls (0.5454,0.2131) and (0.5602,0.3059) .. (0.5319,0.3941) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=49,xscale=-1]
    \penguin@part@draw{\penguin@feet} (0.5319,0.3941) .. controls (0.5138,0.4505) and (0.4245,0.6014) .. (0.3275,0.6533) .. controls (0.2261,0.7075) and (0.2214,0.6369) .. (0.2428,0.5960) .. controls (0.2712,0.5416) and (0.2237,0.5302) .. (0.1952,0.5384) .. controls (0.1022,0.5653) and (0.0298,0.5169) .. (0.1131,0.4340) .. controls (0.1335,0.4137) and (0.2100,0.3557) .. (0.0982,0.3492) .. controls (0.0250,0.3450) and (0.0181,0.2680) .. (0.1082,0.2445) .. controls (0.2000,0.2206) and (0.3206,0.2043) .. (0.4571,0.2096) .. controls (0.5454,0.2131) and (0.5602,0.3059) .. (0.5319,0.3941) -- cycle;
\end{scope}
%
% Eyes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\begin{scope}[xshift=2,yshift=-1]
\fill[\penguin@eye, rotate=-10] 
  (0.38,1.7675) ellipse (0.1 and 0.15);
\penguin@part@draw{\penguin@pupil, rotate=-10} 
  (0.41,1.7575) ellipse (0.0357 and 0.0714);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[xshift=-2,yshift=-1]
\fill[\penguin@eye, rotate=10]
  (1.43,1.44) ellipse (0.1 and 0.15);
\penguin@part@draw{\penguin@pupil, rotate=10}
  (1.4,1.43) ellipse (0.0357 and 0.0714);
\end{scope}  
%
% Bill %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\penguin@part@draw{\penguin@bill} (1.2480,1.4591) .. controls (1.0717,1.3257) and (1.0316,1.4365) .. (0.9225,1.4358) .. controls (0.8205,1.4353) and (0.7596,1.3468) .. (0.6178,1.4542) .. controls (0.8470,0.9682) and (1.1004,1.1827) .. (1.2480,1.4591) -- cycle;
%
}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \penguin
    \duck[invisible,tophat=gray!60!black]
\end{tikzpicture}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \penguin[3D]
\end{tikzpicture}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Please, make a package of it.

Comment: @AlexG I'm thinking about making a `tikzzoo` package - just need to find some time to do it :)

Comment: @AlexG FYI: https://github.com/samcarter8/tikzzoo/blob/master/tikzbears.sty

Comment: @samcarter I cannot find any repository at the github account you linked (only few forks).

Comment: @pushpen.paul Since my last comment, the package was renamed to https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings (I updated the links in the answer, but missed the comment)

Comment: @samcarter Consider adding a robot to your zoo.... :-)

Comment: @pushpen.paul Oh good idea. In case you have a github account, please consider opening a feature request for this: https://github.com/samcarter/tikzlings/issues

Comment: @samcarter Not in github yet... Hopefully someone else will do that...

Answer (score 20):

<sub>Sadly, the code for *Mr. Dinosaur* is too long, so I have to [link it externally here](https://gist.github.com/cereda/fa9b2e1f2f3fb39fe05003469943bb5e).</sub>

> For those who are wondering who is this bloke, here is a reference background (from [Peppa Pig Wiki](http://peppapig.wikia.com/wiki/Mr._Dinosaur)): *Mr. Dinosaur* ​is George Pig's favourite toy, based on a T-Rex.

The integration with `tikzducks` is quite straightforward:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[cap]
\node [xshift=15] at (wing) {\scalebox{.12}{\mrdinosaur}};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: George duck]

*Dinosaur! Grrrr!* `:)`

Answer (score 19):

A video has been made with the help of the tikzducks package.

[image]

The complete video is here https://vimeo.com/246256860

The code is on github (too large and too many files for an answer)
https://github.com/cereda/duck-extravaganza

A few teasers:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 19):

Finally, a *marmot*!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%right foot
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=-0.03cm,yshift=0.12cm},scale=0.7]
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates 
\shade[smooth,upper right=white!30!black,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates
{(1.4,0)(2,0.08)(3,0.08)(3.6,0.3)(3,0.5)(2.4,0.65)(2,0.6)(1.6,0.4)(1.4,0)};
\end{scope}
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %left foot
\shade[smooth,upper right=white!30!black,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates
{(1.4,0)(2,0.08)(3,0.08)(3.6,0.3)(3,0.5)(2.4,0.65)(2,0.6)(1.6,0.4)(1.4,0)};
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %body
\shade[smooth,upper left=brown!70!black,upper right=brown,lower left=black!50!brown,upper
    right=orange,lower right=orange!50!brown,smooth] plot coordinates
{(1.8,8.85)(1.3,8)(1,7)(0.97,6)(1,5)(1.18,4)(1.25,3)(1.39,2)(1.6,1)(1.8,0.6)(2,0.4)(3,0.2)(4,0)(5,0.1)(6,0.3)(6.6,0.45)(7,0.5)%tail
(8,0.7)(8.5,1)(9,1.45)(9.3,2)(9.4,2.6)(9.35,3)(9.2,3.48)(9,3.6)(8.9,3.6)(8.6,3.5)(8.48,3)(8.4,2.4)(8.3,2)(8,1.6)(7.6,1.35)(7.4,1.3)(7.2,1.35)(6.95,1.35)%end tail
(6.82,2)(6.65,3)(6.45,4)(6.28,5)(6.22,6)(6.03,7)(5.85,8)(5.75,9)(5.55,10)(5.25,11)%ear position
(4.5,12)(4,12.1)(3,12.15)(2.5,12.15)(2,11.85)(1.1,11.3)%nose position
(0.8,11.1)(0.65,11)(0.6,10.8)(0.8,10)(1,9.6)(1.4,9.15)(1.8,8.85)};
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %face
\shade[smooth,upper left=white!90!black,upper right=white!80!black,lower
left=white!75!black,upper right=white!85!black,lower right=orange!50!brown,smooth] plot coordinates
{(2.6,8.6)(2.5,9)(2.4,9.5)(2.45,10)(2,10.8)(1.8,11)(1.1,11.3)%from now on as above
(0.8,11.1)(0.65,11)(0.6,10.8)(0.8,10)(1,9.6)(1.4,9.15)(1.8,8.85)};
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %nose
\shade[smooth,upper right=white,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates
{(1.1,11.3)(0.8,11.1)(0.65,11)(0.6,10.8)(0.7,10.45)(1,10.5)(1.3,10.8)(1.3,11)(1.1,11.3)};
\shade[smooth,upper right=black!80!white,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates %mouth
{(0.8,10)(1.2,9.8)(1.5,10)(1.4,9.6)(1.2,9.5)(1,9.6)(0.8,10)};
\draw[smooth,black,thick,fill=white] plot coordinates %teeth
{(1,9.82)(1,9.55)(1.1,9.53)(1.11,9.73)(1.12,9.51)(1.22,9.51)(1.32,9.84)(1.33,9.86)(1,9.82)};
\draw[smooth,brown,thick] plot coordinates %chin
{(1.8,8.85)(2.6,8.6)(3,8.58)(4,8.5)};
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %ears
\shade[smooth,upper left=brown!70!black,upper right=brown!80!black,lower left=black!50!brown,upper
    right=orange!20!brown,lower right=orange!25!brown,smooth] plot coordinates
{(4.9,11.1)(5.4,11.4)(5.4,11.8)(5.2,11.95)(4.8,11.9)(4.6,11.6)(4.9,11.1)};
\shade[smooth,upper left=white](2.8,10.8) circle (0.4); %outer eye
\shade[upper right=white,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black](2.74,10.8) circle (0.27); inner eye
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0}]
%\draw[smooth,black,thick] plot coordinates %left arm
\shade[upper left=brown!70!black,upper right=brown!80!black,lower left=black!50!brown,upper
    right=orange!20!brown,lower right=orange!25!brown,smooth] plot coordinates
{(3.5,5.6)(2.5,5.5)(1.35,5.85)(1.2,6)(1.3,6.3)(1.35,6.4)(2.4,6.8)(3,7)(3.5,5.6)};
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %left claws
\shade[upper right=white!30!black,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates
{(0.8,5.2)(1,5.6)(1.6,6)(1.62,6.2)(1.5,6.5)(1,6.45)(0.75,6.2)(0.6,6)(0.5,5.5)(0.75,5.65)(0.8,5.2)};
\end{scope}
\node[ellipse callout, draw,text width=1.8cm,text centered, callout
 relative pointer={(1.5,-1)},fill=white] at (-1.4,11.3) (hallo) {I love ducks!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

There are claims that marmots are very relevant to string theory...

```
\documentclass[border=4pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
%right foot
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=-0.03cm,yshift=0.12cm},scale=0.7]
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates 
\shade[smooth,draw=white,upper right=white!30!black,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates
{(1.4,0)(2,0.08)(3,0.08)(3.6,0.3)(3,0.5)(2.4,0.65)(2,0.6)(1.6,0.4)(1.4,0)};
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={yshift=-0.13cm,xshift=0.32cm}]
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %left foot
\shade[smooth,draw=white,upper right=white!30!black,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates
{(1.4,0)(2,0.08)(3,0.08)(3.6,0.3)(3,0.5)(2.4,0.65)(2,0.6)(1.6,0.4)(1.4,0)};
\end{scope}
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %body
\shade[smooth,upper left=brown!70!black,upper right=brown,lower left=black!50!brown,upper
    right=orange,lower right=orange!50!brown,smooth] plot coordinates
{(1.8,8.85)(1.3,8)(1,7)(0.97,6)(1,5)(1.18,4)(1.25,3)(1.39,2)(1.6,1)(1.8,0.6)(2,0.4)(3,0.2)(4,0)(5,0.1)(6,0.3)(6.6,0.45)(7,0.5)%tail
(8,0.7)(8.5,1)(9,1.45)(9.3,2)(9.4,2.6)(9.35,3)(9.2,3.48)(9,3.6)(8.9,3.6)(8.6,3.5)(8.48,3)(8.4,2.4)(8.3,2)(8,1.6)(7.6,1.35)(7.4,1.3)(7.2,1.35)(6.95,1.35)%end tail
(6.82,2)(6.65,3)(6.45,4)(6.28,5)(6.22,6)(6.03,7)(5.85,8)(5.75,9)(5.55,10)(5.25,11)%ear position
(4.5,12)(4,12.1)(3,12.15)(2.5,12.15)(2,11.85)(1.1,11.3)%nose position
(0.8,11.1)(0.65,11)(0.6,10.8)(0.8,10)(1,9.6)(1.4,9.15)(1.8,8.85)};
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %face
\shade[smooth,upper left=white!90!black,upper right=white!80!black,lower
left=white!75!black,upper right=white!85!black,lower right=orange!50!brown,smooth] plot coordinates
{(2.6,8.6)(2.5,9)(2.4,9.5)(2.45,10)(2,10.8)(1.8,11)(1.1,11.3)%from now on as above
(0.8,11.1)(0.65,11)(0.6,10.8)(0.8,10)(1,9.6)(1.4,9.15)(1.8,8.85)};
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %nose
\shade[smooth,upper right=white,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates
{(1.1,11.3)(0.8,11.1)(0.65,11)(0.6,10.8)(0.7,10.45)(1,10.5)(1.3,10.8)(1.3,11)(1.1,11.3)};
\shade[smooth,upper right=black!80!white,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates %mouth
{(0.8,10)(1.2,9.8)(1.5,10)(1.4,9.6)(1.2,9.5)(1,9.6)(0.8,10)};
\draw[smooth,black,thick,fill=white] plot coordinates %teeth
{(1,9.82)(1,9.55)(1.1,9.53)(1.11,9.73)(1.12,9.51)(1.22,9.51)(1.32,9.84)(1.33,9.86)(1,9.82)};
\draw[smooth,brown,thick] plot coordinates %chin
{(1.8,8.85)(2.6,8.6)(3,8.58)};
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %ears
\shade[smooth,upper left=brown!70!black,upper right=brown!80!black,lower left=black!50!brown,upper
    right=orange!20!brown,lower right=orange!25!brown,smooth] plot coordinates
{(4.9,11.1)(5.4,11.4)(5.4,11.8)(5.2,11.95)(4.8,11.9)(4.6,11.6)(4.9,11.1)};
\shade[smooth,upper left=white](2.8,10.8) circle (0.4); %outer eye
\shade[upper right=white,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black](2.74,10.8) circle (0.27); inner eye
\begin{scope}[transform canvas={xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=0}]
%\draw[smooth,black,thick] plot coordinates %left arm
\shade[upper left=brown!70!black,upper right=brown!80!black,lower left=black!50!brown,upper
    right=orange!20!brown,lower right=orange!25!brown,smooth] plot coordinates
{(3.5,5.6)(2.5,5.5)(1.35,5.85)(1.2,6)(1.3,6.3)(1.35,6.4)(2.4,6.8)(3,7)(3.5,5.6)};
%\draw[smooth,blue,thick] plot coordinates %left claws
\shade[upper right=white!30!black,lower left=black,lower right=black,upper left=black] plot coordinates
{(0.8,5.2)(1,5.6)(1.6,6)(1.62,6.2)(1.5,6.5)(1,6.45)(0.75,6.2)(0.6,6)(0.5,5.5)(0.75,5.65)(0.8,5.2)};
\end{scope}
\node[ellipse callout, draw,text width=1.8cm,text centered, callout
 relative pointer={(1,-0.5)},fill=white] at (-1.5,11.8) (11D) {11D
 supergravity};
\node[ellipse callout, draw,text width=1.8cm,text centered, callout
 relative pointer={(-0.5,-0.1)},fill=white] at (7.4,12) (hetE8) {heterotic
 E$_8\times$E$_8$};
\node[ellipse callout, draw,text width=1.8cm,text centered, callout
 relative pointer={(0.2,-0.6)},fill=white] at (8.4,5) (hetSO) {heterotic
 SO(32)};
\node[ellipse callout, draw,text width=1.8cm,text centered, callout
 relative pointer={(0.8,-0.4)},fill=white] at (-1.4,7) (typeI) {type I};
\node[ellipse callout, draw,text width=1.8cm,text centered, callout
 relative pointer={(1.2,-0.8)},fill=white] at (-0.8,1.4) (typeIIA) {type IIA};
\node[ellipse callout, draw,text width=1.8cm,text centered, callout
 relative pointer={(1.6,-0.05)},fill=white] at (-1.4,0) (typeIIB) {type IIB};
\node(M) at (2,14){\Huge Does M stand for marmot?};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How did we survive without a marmot?

Comment: @ArtificialStupidity Yes, I'm aware of this. That's why I wrote that I intend to edit this later. Actually, I am trying to convince LaTeX or the editor to do that 4 me. (Of course, I know how to strip of the digits, I am asking about the removal of unnecessary coordinates.) Any suggestions?

Comment: Wow! Great contribution to the duck pond!

Comment: That's really a marmot and not a cross between a beaver and a penguin?

Comment: @marmot Of course marmots are good at string theory, if the strings don't behave, they can simply nibble on the string until they do what the marmots want :) With these teeth, creating a unified theory is a piece of cake!

Comment: @samcarter Your `tikzmarmots` is missing here! ;-)

Comment: @Ignasi They are no longer missing :)

Answer (score 18):

I missed a beard for the "santa" duck.

It might not be pretty, and the code is definitely not pretty. 
But being a novice at LaTeX I'm happy with it!

```
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[santa=red!80!black, jacket=red!80!gray, tshirt=white,];

    %This prompts the beard%
    \fill[white!80!brown](1.3,1.3) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (1.2,1.15) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.5,1.05) ellipse (0.1 and 0.1);
    \fill[white!80!brown](0.525,0.90) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.525,0.75) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.65,0.65) ellipse (0.14 and 0.14);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.75,0.75) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.85,0.85) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.95,0.95) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (1.05,1.05) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (1.15,1.25) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (1,1.20) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.85,1.20) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.75,1.15) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.65,1.10) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.58,1.07) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.42,1.46) ellipse (0.07 and 0.07);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.52,1.45) ellipse (0.07 and 0.07);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.6,1.44) ellipse (0.07 and 0.07);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.68,1.40) ellipse (0.07 and 0.07);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.76,1.36) ellipse (0.07 and 0.07);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.8,1.25) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.85,1.28) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (0.38,1.44) ellipse (0.05 and 0.05);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (1,1.28) ellipse (0.12 and 0.12);
    \fill[white!80!brown] (1.3,1.3) -- (0.5,1.05) -- (0.65,0.65) -- cycle;

    %Beard ends here%

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Santa duck with beard]

Merry Chirstmas!

/Mihikma

[image: Quack]

Comment: ... and welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: Really Fantastic!! Too bad I already printed my X-mas cards :(

Comment: <3 <3 <3 I'll use it for my Xmas cards!

Comment: Absolutely fantastic!

Comment: This answer has the duck official approval!

Comment: @Mihikma Can we add it to `tikzducks` package?

Comment: Oh and a Merry Christmas to you too!

Comment: @Mihikma May I add something similar to the `tikzducks` package? Of course I'd give credit to you.

Comment: @samcarter Yes! Definitely. Go ahead!

Comment: @Mihikma Thanks! I added the beard to the development version. In case you want to have a look: https://github.com/samcarter8/tikzducks

Comment: @Mihikma The beard is now available from ctan: https://ctan.org/pkg/tikzducks?lang=en

Answer (score 16):

A [Ulysses butterfly](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/f3/Papilio_ulysses_ambiguus_Rothschild%2C_1895.JPG) made using the `tikz` and `animate` packages. The wings flap intermittently.

[image]

It might be possible to adapt this code to create other species of butterflies. If anyone does this please tag me to show me what you create. I'd love to see it. :)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,landscape]{article}
%\documentclass[export]{standalone}
% All design and code created by Ulysses. Please credit me if you use a significant portion of this anywhere.

\usepackage[margin=0.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{times}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}

\newcommand{\halfwing}[1]{
\begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=#1]
    % Lower Wing
    \filldraw[fill=black!90!white!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=1mm] (0,0.2) -- (0,1.4) -- (-2,1.4) .. controls (-4,0.8) .. (-4.3,0.2) .. controls (-4.48,0.08) .. (-4.5,-0.15) .. controls (-4.9,-0.5) and (-4.9,-0.7) .. (-4.7,-0.9) .. controls (-4.7,-1) .. (-4.6,-1.1) .. controls (-4.9,-1.8) .. (-4.2,-2) -- (-4,-2.4) .. controls (-4.1,-3) .. (-3.6,-3.1) -- (-3.25,-3.7) .. controls (-3.5,-4.5) .. (-4.1,-5.4) .. controls (-4.2,-5.9) and (-3.6,-5.9) .. (-3.5,-5.4) .. controls (-3.55,-5.1) and (-3.4,-4.8) .. (-3,-4.1) -- (-2.6,-4.1) .. controls (-2.35,-4.35) .. (-2,-4.2) .. controls (-1.75,-4.6) and (-1.25,-4.6) .. (-1.25,-3.90) .. controls (-0.9,-4) .. (-0.6,-2.8) -- (-0.3,-1) -- (0,0.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!45!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black,rounded corners=1mm] (-0.8,-3) .. controls (-0.5,-2) .. (-0.30,-0.95){[rounded corners=0mm] .. controls (-0.15,-0.3) .. (-0.05,0.45) -- (-0.05,0.7)} -- (-0.7,0.4) .. controls (-0.9,-2) .. (-0.8,-3);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!60!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-1.1,-2.9) .. controls (-1.4,2) and (0.5,2) .. (-1.1,-2.9);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!70!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-1.6,-2.8) .. controls (-0.9,3.7) and (0,-0.1) .. (-1.6,-2.8);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!70!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-2.1,-2.6) .. controls (-0.9,3.7) and (-0.3,-0.1) .. (-2.1,-2.6);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-2.6,-2.2) .. controls (-0.3,3.7) and (-0.3,-0.1) .. (-2.6,-2.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-3,-1.7) .. controls (0.1,3.7) and (0.1,-0.1) .. (-3,-1.7);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-3.4,-1.2) .. controls (0.77,3) and (0.77,-0.2) .. (-3.4,-1.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!20!cyan!,draw=black] (-3.6,-0.6) .. controls (0.77,2.2) and (0.77,-0.5) .. (-3.6,-0.6);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!15!cyan!,draw=black] (-3.5,0) .. controls (0.77,1.8) and (0.77,-0.2) .. (-3.5,0);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!80!cyan!,bottom color=blue!10!cyan!,draw=black] (-2.5,0.7) .. controls (0.77,2) and (0.77,0) .. (-2.5,0.7);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!45!cyan!,bottom color=blue!15!cyan!,draw=black] (-0.05,0.6) -- (-0.05,0.9) .. controls (-4,-0.5) and (-1.5,-2) .. (-0.05,0.6);

    % Upper Wing
    \filldraw[fill=black!90!white!,draw=black,thick] (0,1) -- (0,2.2) [rounded corners=7mm] parabola[bend at end] (-6,6) -- (-5,1) -- (0,1);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!20!cyan!,bottom color=blue!70!cyan!,draw=black] (-4,3.5) .. controls (3,-1) and (-2,4) .. (-4,3.5);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!15!cyan!,bottom color=blue,draw=black] (-4.1,3) .. controls (3.9,-0.5) and (-2.1,4) .. (-4.1,3);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!15!cyan!,bottom color=blue!80!cyan!,draw=black] (-4.2,2.5) .. controls (4,-0.2) and (-2.2,3.5) .. (-4.2,2.5);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!15!cyan!,bottom color=blue!70!cyan!,draw=black] (-4.2,1.8) .. controls (4,0.3) and (-2.2,3) .. (-4.2,1.8);
    \shadedraw[top color=cyan,bottom color=blue!60!cyan!,draw=black] (-4.2,1.2) .. controls (4.05,0.9) and (-2.2,2.4) .. (-4.2,1.2);
    \shadedraw[top color=cyan,bottom color=blue!60!cyan!,draw=black] (-0.05,1.85) -- (-0.05,1.80) .. controls (-6.5,6.5) and (-2,5.5) .. (-0.05,1.85);
    \shadedraw[top color=blue!10!cyan!,bottom color=blue!50!cyan!,draw=black] (-0.05,1.8) -- (-0.05,1.4) .. controls (-7.5,5.5) and (-2,5) .. (-0.05,1.8);
\end{scope}
}

\newcommand{\butterfly}[1]{
\begin{tikzpicture}
    % Guide lines
    %\draw[step=1cm,lightgray,very thin] (-20,-14) grid (20,14);
    %\begin{scope}[xshift=-0.35cm]
    %\draw[step=0.2cm,lightgray,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (0,2);
    %\draw[step=1cm,cyan,very thin] (-7,-7) grid (0,2);
    %\end{scope}

    % Background
    \filldraw[color=cyan!20!white!,draw=black, line width=3pt] (0,0) circle (10cm);

    % Text
    \draw (0,-7) node {\Huge Papilio Ulysses};
    \draw[decoration={text along path,text={Design and code created by Ulysses.},text align={center}},decorate,rotate=90] (0,0) circle (9.8cm);

    % Antenna
    \draw[thick] (0,2.7) parabola[bend at end] (-1.5,5.2);
    \filldraw[fill=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick] (-1.5,5.2) .. controls ++(-0.2,0.1) and ++(-0.5,-0.3) .. ++(0,0);
    \begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1]
    \draw[thick] (0,2.7) parabola[bend at end] (-1.5,5.2);
    \filldraw[fill=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick] (-1.5,5.2) .. controls ++(-0.2,0.1) and ++(-0.5,-0.3) .. ++(0,0);
    \end{scope}

    % Body
    \filldraw[fill=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2.5mm] (0,2.5) -- (0.35,2.5) -- (0.45,1.5) -- (0.45,0) -- (0.25,-2) -- (-0.25,-2) -- (-0.45,0) -- (-0.45,1.5) -- (-0.35,2.5) -- (0,2.5);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,2.24) ellipse (0.35cm and 0.24cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,1.75) ellipse (0.4cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,1.25) ellipse (0.42cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,0.75) ellipse (0.42cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,0.25) ellipse (0.42cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-0.25) ellipse (0.4cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-0.75) ellipse (0.35cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-1.25) ellipse (0.3cm and 0.25cm);
    \shade[inner color=black!70!white!,outer color=black!80!white!] (0,-1.74) ellipse (0.25cm and 0.24cm);

    % Head
    \shadedraw[inner color=black!60!white!,outer color=black!80!white!,draw=black,thick,rounded corners=2mm] (0,3) -- (0.45,3) -- (0.2,2.3) -- (-0.2,2.3) -- (-0.45,3) -- (0,3);
    \shadedraw[inner color=white!60!black,outer color=black, draw=black,thick] (-0.25,2.85) circle (0.2cm);
    \shadedraw[inner color=white!60!black,outer color=black, draw=black,thick] (0.25,2.85) circle (0.2cm);

    % Wings
    \begin{scope}[xshift=-0.35cm]
    \halfwing{#1}
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[xshift=0.35cm]
    \halfwing{-#1}
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[p]
\centering
\begin{animateinline}[autoplay,loop,scale=1]{13}
    \butterfly{1}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.2}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{1}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.2}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{1}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.2}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.317}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.6}
\newframe
    \butterfly{0.883}
\newframe[1.5]
    \butterfly{1}
\end{animateinline}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Beautiful! I made an [SVG version](https://agrahn.gitlab.io/svg/ulysses.svg) of it. Just added global option `dvisvgm` to `article` and also `\pagestyle{empty}`. Then,  `latex`, finally `dvisvgm --no-fonts --exact --zoom=-1` on the DVI file.

Answer (score 15):

One can also make *very* realistic movies. ;-)

**UPDATE**: Made use of a `transparency group`. This avoids making hidden parts visible. Presumably it is always a good idea to use a `transparency group` if you want to play with the `opacity` of a tikzling.

```
\documentclass[border=3.14mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,marmots,ducks,3d,shapes.callouts,calc}
\makeatletter % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48776/121799
\tikzoption{canvas is xy plane at z}[]{%
  \def\tikz@plane@origin{\pgfpointxyz{0}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@x{\pgfpointxyz{1}{0}{#1}}%
  \def\tikz@plane@y{\pgfpointxyz{0}{1}{#1}}%
  \tikz@canvas@is@plane
}
\makeatother
%
\tikzset{
brick height/.store in=\BrickHeight, 
brick height=10pt,
brick width/.store in=\BrickWidth, 
brick width=20pt,
}

\tikzset{Wall/.style args={with colors #1 and #2}{path picture={
\fill[#1] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north east)-(path picture bounding
box.south west)$), \n1={int(scalar(\x1/\BrickWidth)+1))},
\n2={int(scalar(\y1/\BrickHeight)+1)} in
foreach \WallX in {1,...,\n1}
 {foreach \WallY in {1,...,\n2}
 {($(path picture bounding box.south west)+({(\WallX-2)*\BrickWidth},
 {(\WallY-1)*\BrickWidth})$) rectangle ++ (2*\BrickWidth,2*\BrickHeight)}
};
\draw[#2] let \p1=($(path picture bounding box.north east)-(path picture bounding
box.south west)$), \n1={int(scalar(\x1/\BrickWidth)+1))},
\n2={int(scalar(\y1/\BrickHeight)+1)} in
foreach \WallX in {1,...,\n1}
 {foreach \WallY in {1,...,\n2}
 {($(path picture bounding box.south west)+({(\WallX-2)*\BrickWidth},
 {(\WallY-1)*\BrickWidth})$)  -- ++ (2*\BrickWidth,0)
 ($(path picture bounding box.south west)+({(\WallX-2)*\BrickWidth},
 {(\WallY-1/2)*\BrickWidth})$)  -- ++ (2*\BrickWidth,0)
 ($(path picture bounding box.south west)+({(\WallX-2)*\BrickWidth},
 {(\WallY-1)*\BrickWidth})$)  -- ++ (0,\BrickHeight)
 ($(path picture bounding box.south west)+({(\WallX-1.5)*\BrickWidth},
 {(\WallY-1.5)*\BrickWidth})$)  -- ++ (0,\BrickHeight)}
};
}}}
\tikzset{pics/.cd,
  duck/.style={code={\duck[#1]}},
  marmot/.style={code={\marmot[#1]}}
}
%
\newcommand\QueenRhyme[1]{\ifcase#1
\or
Mirror,
\or
mirror
\or
on
\or
the
\or
wall,
\or
who
\or
is
\or
the
\or
cutest
\or
of
\or
them
\or
all?
\or
\or
\or
\fi
}
\begin{document}
\tdplotsetmaincoords{110}{-30}
\foreach \X [count=\Y] in {-1,-0.9,...,1}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
 \path[use as bounding box] (-3,-2) rectangle (6,5);
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\xtest}{sign(cos(\tdplotmainphi+90))}
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\ytest}{sign(-cos(\tdplotmainphi))}
 \begin{scope}[tdplot_main_coords]
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape]
   \fill[brown!80!black] (0,0) rectangle (10,8);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=0,transform shape]
    \draw[Wall={with colors gray!50!black and gray!60}] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is xz plane at y=3,transform shape]
      \pic[local bounding box=duck] at (4.5,0.5) {duck={crown,laughing, bill=red,longhair=black}};
      \ifnum\Y<13
       \node[ellipse callout,fill=white, draw,anchor=east, callout absolute
     pointer={(4.7,2)},text width=1.5cm,align=center] 
     (song) at (5.5,3.4) {\QueenRhyme{\Y}};
      \fi
  \end{scope}
  \begin{scope}[canvas is yz plane at x=0,transform shape]
   \draw[Wall={with colors gray!50!black and gray!60}] (0,0) rectangle (10,10);
   \shade[top color=blue!20,bottom color=blue!30,middle color=blue!10] (1.5,1) rectangle (5.5,5);
   \ifnum\Y>10
   \begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=\X]
   \pic at (2.5,1.6) {marmot={whiskers,teeth}};
   \end{scope}
   \fi
  \end{scope}
 \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: ooh marmots and mirrors

Answer (score 14):

The Ti*k*Zducks got a smaller sibling, the Ti*k*Zmarmots:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzmarmots}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \marmot[whiskers,teeth]
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \marmot
    \duck[invisible,crown]
    \begin{scope}[scale=0.7,xshift=9,yshift=18]
        \duck[invisible,cake=red!50!violet]
    \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh my!!! How could we survive so long without? ;-)

Comment: Awwwww.... so cute!

Answer (score 14):

**Chicken out of the egg** - PSTricks:

... as a hint for a **Duckling out of the egg** :-)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\psfs@asolid{\pst@fill{\pst@usecolor\psfillcolor eofill}}
\makeatother

%% Color Definitions
\definecolor{CouleurI}{cmyk}{0,0,0,0}
\definecolor{CouleurII}{cmyk}{.500694,.256565,.266178,0}
\definecolor{CouleurIII}{cmyk}{.00231937,.288243,.807706,0}
\definecolor{CouleurIV}{cmyk}{.000885023,.590173,.93637,0}
\definecolor{CouleurV}{cmyk}{.320531,.93048,.867948,.422095}
\definecolor{CouleurVI}{cmyk}{.163363,.0721752,.0742809,0}

\psscaleboxto(-1,-1){
\psset{unit=0.01}
\begin{pspicture}(0,0)(512,512)
%% Path : 1
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=CouleurII,linestyle=none]{
\moveto(39.111,274.958)
\psline(71.111,227.556)
\psline(113.778,270.222)
\psline(170.667,241.778)
\psline(213.333,284.444)
\psline(270.222,199.111)
\psline(327.111,241.778)
\psline(369.778,227.556)
\psline(398.222,270.222)
\psline(440.889,227.556)
\psline(469.333,284.444)
\psline(440.889,384)
\psline(284.444,455.111)
\psline(128,426.667)
\psline(42.667,341.333)
\psline(39.111,274.958)
\closepath
}
%% Path : 2
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=CouleurIII,linestyle=none]{
\moveto(426.041,209.237)
\psbezier(426.34,205.141)(426.667,201.074)(426.667,196.907)
\psbezier(426.667,112.384)(365.17,42.396)(284.501,28.814)
\psbezier(301.412,25.131)(313.387,21.575)(298.667,14.222)
\psbezier(282.809,6.28601)(266.937,16.057)(256.014,26.24)
\psline(255.986,26.24)
\psbezier(245.049,16.057)(229.205,6.28601)(213.333,14.222)
\psbezier(198.613,21.575)(210.588,25.131)(227.499,28.814)
\psbezier(146.844,42.396)(85.333,112.384)(85.333,196.907)
\psbezier(85.333,201.074)(85.66,205.141)(85.959,209.237)
\psbezier(79.09,303.118)(-3.68301,440.889)(256,440.889)
\psbezier(515.684,440.889)(432.896,303.118)(426.041,209.237)
\closepath
}
%% Path : 3
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=CouleurIV,linestyle=none]{
\moveto(298.667,199.111)
\psbezier(298.667,222.677)(279.566,227.556)(256,227.556)
\psbezier(232.434,227.556)(213.333,222.677)(213.333,199.111)
\psbezier(213.333,175.545)(232.434,156.444)(256,156.444)
\psbezier(279.566,156.444)(298.667,175.545)(298.667,199.111)
\closepath
}
%% Path : 4
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=CouleurV,linestyle=none]{
\moveto(184.889,163.556)
\psbezier(184.889,175.346)(175.346,184.889)(163.556,184.889)
\psbezier(151.765,184.889)(142.222,175.346)(142.222,163.556)
\psbezier(142.222,151.765)(151.765,142.222)(163.556,142.222)
\psbezier(175.346,142.222)(184.889,151.765)(184.889,163.556)
\closepath
}
%% Path : 5
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=CouleurV,linestyle=none]{
\moveto(369.778,163.556)
\psbezier(369.778,175.346)(360.22,184.889)(348.444,184.889)
\psbezier(336.668,184.889)(327.111,175.346)(327.111,163.556)
\psbezier(327.111,151.765)(336.668,142.222)(348.444,142.222)
\psbezier(360.22,142.222)(369.778,151.765)(369.778,163.556)
\closepath
}
%% Path : 6
\pscustom[fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=CouleurVI,linestyle=none]{
\moveto(440.889,355.556)
\psline(398.222,341.333)
\psline(341.333,426.667)
\psline(298.667,355.556)
\psline(270.222,384)
\psline(213.333,355.556)
\psline(170.667,412.444)
\psline(128,327.111)
\psline(85.333,355.556)
\psline(38.485,245.12)
\psbezier(31.986,264.306)(28.444,284.672)(28.444,305.778)
\psbezier(28.444,419.684)(130.332,512)(256,512)
\psbezier(381.668,512)(483.556,419.684)(483.556,305.778)
\psbezier(483.556,288.085)(480.839,271.019)(476.203,254.62)
\psline(440.889,355.556)
\closepath
}
\end{pspicture}
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Nowadays there is a trend of making things expandable. So here is an expandable duck.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=0.5cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usepgfmodule{nonlineartransformations} 
\makeatletter
\def\expandabletransformation{% similar to the pgfmanual section 103.4.2
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{ifthenelse(\pgf@x<0,\pgf@x,%
ifthenelse(\pgf@x<\myxmax,10*\pgf@x,\pgf@x+(\myxmax-1)*10))}
\pgf@x=\myx pt%
} 
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {0,10,...,350}
{\pgfmathsetmacro{\myxmax}{5.5+4.5*sin(\X)}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path[use as bounding box] (-3,0) rectangle (5,4.5);
\begin{scope}
 \pgftransformnonlinear{\expandabletransformation}
 \duck[scale=2,xshift=-1.4cm]
\end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

At CarLaTeX's request, triggered by [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/408898/121799) and [that answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408948/121799), working my way up to the `\marmot` command. ;-)

```
\documentclass[12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shadings}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.callouts}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\shade[upper left=red,upper left=brown,lower left=black!50!brown,upper
right=orange,lower right=orange!50!brown,smooth]
plot coordinates {(8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975)  (8.653420477717171,5.393068158849042)  (8.897979068613598,5.784361904283323)  (9.054496566787309,6.151199790627962)  (9.176775862235523,6.635425800602885)  (9.31861984495545,7.222366418754307)  (9.343075704045093,7.8728922705388)  (9.308837501319593,8.293533046880652)  (9.157211174963809,8.538091637777077)  (8.85395852225224,8.391356483239223)  (8.443100089546245,7.956042191443585)  (8.076262203201606,7.579421961463089)  (7.748553691400395,7.232148762390164)  (7.4501922105067555,6.811507986048312)  (7.279001196879258,6.459343615157459)  (7.176286588702759,6.038702838815606)  (7.773848252993539,7.404007626215198)  (7.819564427995601,7.651505539157395)  (7.8264669877139506,7.867492374912536)  (7.804077433222327,8.056204334199078)  (7.727313246393903,8.254511816839173)  (7.608968458366749,8.372856604866326)  (7.465035608063454,8.414437206065056)  (7.285919172130465,8.38245212821988)  (7.0716191505677815,8.216129723424961)  (6.863716144574133,7.944256561740961)  (6.738974340977944,7.649993845565335)  (6.665408661934038,7.4548848707097575)  (6.668607169718555,7.090254983274744)  (6.646217615226932,6.610478815597094)  (6.604737979609691,6.154467171231563)  (6.5529724229494555,5.787402314913527)  (6.463559188718139,5.5756341285761994)  (6.1529658487567245,5.330924224364176)  (5.757665234260378,5.114450078330462)  (5.354877070877689,4.897975137756692)  (5.,4.5)  (4.821479324121693,4.163687330534155)  (4.6136620201907865,3.858888618102158)  (4.530535098618423,3.6372168272425243)  (4.436895027217463,3.5000557234720557)  (4.349819298957242,3.3215504805386034)  (4.317165900859659,3.1365145579856346)  (4.328050366892187,2.9471248490196547)  (4.347642405750737,2.7707964992927083)  (4.450381667535669,2.5159314321415236)  (4.532041887458237,2.3563228204746856)  (4.7881580317608385,2.2264088342342356)  (5.059121488776634,2.0779357071022933)  (5.344932258505623,1.899767954543962)  (5.484652825467143,1.8292695614504035)  (5.506329987815211,1.737194466087021)  (5.476711191510275,1.4854346974950627)  (5.617400473958722,1.0966879959927742)  (5.958016631465489,0.27106404899267567)  (6.269309791973645,-0.2515451024553113)  (6.6694882347995845,-0.7059850290542589)  (7.07644936309715,-0.96372707697605)  (7.395235580263576,-1.0315539316923108)  (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281) (7.496975862337968,-1.1400768992383281)  (7.5,-1.5)  (7.35453946743382,-1.7573012771563017)  (7.0696666776255235,-1.8522588737590668)  (6.696618976686088,-1.9607818413050841)  (6.506703783480558,-2.1778277763971188)  (6.330353961218279,-2.367742969602649)  (6.316788590275027,-2.5780062192230577)  (7.083232048568776,-2.6187023320528144)  (7.754717910259759,-2.6187023320528144)  (8.236288578745212,-2.5712235337514318)  (8.453334513837248,-2.354177598659397)  (8.751772674588796,-2.0693048088511015)  (8.98916666609571,-1.8115627609293103)  (9.165516488357987,-1.540255342064267)  (9.33447506356106,-1.3968710396354151)  (9.6,-1.4)  (9.883136971295853,-1.5659555269247534)  (10.228207353518993,-1.7660963486141739)  (10.664976183641343,-1.9674263178593647)  (10.841494002882714,-2.0195793099079515)  (10.973882367313742,-2.0998146822903925)  (10.921729375265155,-2.2482501211979082)  (10.941788218360765,-2.4287797090584)  (11.142376649316867,-2.60529752829977)  (11.59570650327766,-2.653438751729235)  (12.237589482337189,-2.617332834157136)  (12.662836955964126,-2.5772151479659158)  (13.148260958877895,-2.505003312821719)  (14.344478214484807,-2.502493194173754)  (15.369243602427948,-2.3819325602980905)  (15.851486137930603,-1.759035951940496)  (16.18302788108868,-0.8548311978730202)  (15.640505028648192,-0.9151115148108518)  (15.781159101503134,-0.1515608335983167)  (15.469710797324336,0.9736717492412088)  (14.746346994070354,2.1089510515703727)  (13.741901035087823,3.0462093916695716)  (12.74202561081047,3.652194497292207)  (11.620953165408594,4.04608481594692)  (10.378683698882188,4.076384071228052)  (9.424257157526535,3.8794389119006953)  (8.833421679544463,3.833990028978998)  (8.484980243811448,4.030935188306354)  (8.257735829202957,4.364226996398804)  (8.247996636798005,4.764611473259732)  (8.487120635907601,5.055577303411975)};

\draw[thick,smooth,brown] plot coordinates { (10.970355256269126,-1.9322725401224543)  (11.047142365016613,-1.7786983226274815)  (11.215647409212487,-1.6443208823193802)  (11.492934190800634,-1.5440710458990508)  (11.787284774332665,-1.5355391449271076)  (12.077369407378725,-1.4886136895814215)  (12.416294906384667,-1.4948048149804178)  (12.799824433796168,-1.5628503762953614)  (13.090564559414563,-1.714406399224099)  (13.310166143658245,-1.8845203025114576)};

\draw[thick,smooth,fill=black] plot coordinates { (6.176715812497315,3.9442760413021656)  (6.433821047703658,3.9250890834509464)  (6.671739325058781,3.963462999153385)  (6.834828466794148,4.115039966178019)  (6.8309910752239045,4.35295824353314)  (6.712031936546342,4.475754773780944)  (6.512487574893659,4.535234343119725)  (6.3263740837368285,4.483429556921433)  (6.159447550431217,4.329933894111677)  (6.14217928836512,4.180275622872165)  (6.16136624621634,4.045966917913629)  (6.1460166799353635,3.932763866591434)};

\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates { (4.9,3.4)  (4.867460280572349,3.253821969982106)  (4.719583397599846,3.1622025968360994)  (4.623141952182997,3.0657611514192507)  (4.507412217682777,3.138092235481887)  (4.404541342571471,3.3149015520794434)};

\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates { (4.652234498957524,2.8886104804097017)  (4.769852024033724,2.977169558114133)  (4.9137605253034256,3.1487527711664685)  (4.978796097992618,3.2926612724361695)};

\draw[ultra thick,smooth] plot coordinates { (4.589966397446596,2.870621917750989)  (4.4751163435486605,2.945343639564103)  (4.40316209291381,3.072647313764223)  (4.378254852309438,3.220707021801319)};

 \node[ellipse callout, draw,text width=1.8cm,text centered, callout
 relative pointer={(0.5,-1)},fill=white] at (3.7,5) (hallo) {I love marmots!};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 (even if this is a community wiki and you won't get reputation for it) :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX That's fine, I really like the rabbit's statement ;-)

Comment: Ducks love marmots too :)

Comment: @CarLaTeX OK, they no longer have to wait. ;-)

Answer (score 13):

This is more work in progress. A first attempt to adapt @samcarter's stellar `tikzduck` and `tikzmarmot` packages to draw koalas. This is the style file

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% The tikzkoalas package
% A package to bring little koalas into tikz
% Maintained by ...
%
% Project repository and bug tracker:
% ...
%
% Released under the LaTeX Project Public License v1.3c or later
% See http://www.latex-project.org/lppl.txt
%
% Version 0.1
% August 29, 2018  
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ProvidesPackage{tikzkoalas}
 [2018/08/29 v0.1 Drawing koalas in TikZ]

\RequirePackage{tikzducks}

\usetikzlibrary{fadings} 

\tikzfading[name=tikzling@blush,
inner color=transparent!50,
outer color=transparent!100]



\newcommand*{\koala}[1][]{%
    \begin{scope}%
        \tikzset{/koala/.cd,#1}%
        \koala@draw%
    \end{scope}%
}

\newif\ifkoala@name
\newif\ifkoala@blush
\newif\ifkoala@whiskers
\newif\ifkoala@sleeping
\newif\ifkoala@threeD

\definecolor{koala@gray}{RGB}{160,160,160}

\tikzset{
  %
  % Pass unknown keys on to tikz
  %
  /koala/.search also={/tikz,/pgf},
  /koala/.cd,
  name/.code         = \koala@nametrue \def\koala@name{#1},
  %
  % body
  %
  body/.code         = \def\koala@body{#1},
  body               = koala@gray,
  %
  % options
  %
  blush/.code            = \koala@blushtrue,
  sleeping/.code        = \koala@sleepingtrue,
  3D/.code           = \koala@threeDtrue,
}




\def\koala@draw{%
\ifkoala@threeD
        \def\koala@part@draw[##1]{\shade[ball color=##1]}
\else
        \def\koala@part@draw[##1]{\fill[##1]}
\fi
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% minimal bounding box size 
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\path (0.3,0.1) rectangle (1.83,2.17);
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Body parts
% 
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Feet %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\fill[\koala@body!50!black] (1.18,0.2) ellipse (0.23 and 0.09); 
\fill[\koala@body!50!black] (0.67,0.2) ellipse (0.23 and 0.09);
%
% Ears %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\koala@part@draw[\koala@body] (1.33,2.13) ellipse (0.3 and 0.23);
\fill[\koala@body!40!white] (1.33,2.13) ellipse (0.15 and 0.12);
\koala@part@draw[\koala@body] (0.52,2.13) ellipse (0.3 and 0.23);
\fill[\koala@body!40!white] (0.52,2.13) ellipse (0.15 and 0.12);
%
% Body %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\koala@part@draw[\koala@body] (1.48,0.92) .. controls (1.48,0.26) and (1.28,0.18) .. (0.95,0.18) .. controls (0.61,0.18) and (0.28,0.26) .. (0.28,0.92) .. controls (0.28,1.58) and (0.59,2.17) .. (0.92,2.17) .. controls (1.25,2.17) and (1.48,1.58) .. (1.48,0.92) -- cycle;
%
% Head %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\koala@part@draw[\koala@body] (0.925,1.7) ellipse (0.55 and 0.45);
%
% Belly %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\koala@part@draw[\koala@body!40!white] (1.35,0.71) .. controls (1.35,0.41) and (1.17,0.27) .. (0.92,0.27) .. controls (0.69,0.27) and (0.48,0.41) .. (0.48,0.71) .. controls (0.48,1.01) and (0.67,1.26) .. (0.91,1.26) .. controls (1.15,1.26) and (1.35,1.01) .. (1.35,0.71) -- cycle;
%
% Arms %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\koala@part@draw[\koala@body,rotate around={-110:(0.3,1)}] (0.3,1) ellipse (0.42 and 0.13);
\fill[\koala@body!50!black,rotate around={-20:(0.18,0.65)}] (0.18,0.65) ellipse (0.12 and 0.08);
\koala@part@draw[\koala@body,rotate around={-70:(1.55,1)}] (1.55,1) ellipse (0.42 and 0.13);
\fill[\koala@body!50!black,rotate around={20:(1.67,0.65)}] (1.67,0.65) ellipse (0.12 and 0.08);
%
% Nose %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\shade[ball color=black] (0.775,1.6) to[out=-110,in=180] (0.925,1.45)
to[out=0,in=-70] (1.075,1.6) to[out=110,in=-45] (1,1.74)
to[out=135,in=45] (0.85,1.74) to[out=-135,in=70] cycle;
%(0.925,1.6) circle (0.15);
%
% Eyes %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ifkoala@sleeping
    \draw[thin] (0.59,1.77) arc (180:360:0.08 and 0.04);
    \draw[ultra thin] (0.59,1.77) arc (180:0:0.08 and 0.08);
    \draw[thin] (1.26,1.77) arc (0:-180:0.08 and 0.04);
    \draw[ultra thin] (1.26,1.77) arc (0:180:0.08 and 0.08);
    \foreach \koala@X in {-135,-112.5,-90,-67.5,-45}
     { \draw[very thin] (0.67,1.77) ++(\koala@X:0.08 and 0.04)  -- 
     ++ ({(\koala@X+90)/2-90}:0.06 and 0.03);
     \draw[very thin] (1.18,1.77) ++(\koala@X:0.08 and 0.04)  -- 
     ++ ({-90+(90+\koala@X)/2}:0.06 and 0.03);} 
\else
    \shade[ball color=black] (0.67,1.77) circle (0.08); 
    \shade[ball color=black] (1.18,1.77) circle (0.08); 
\fi
%
% Mouth %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ifkoala@threeD
    \draw[black,thick] (1.02,1.42) arc [start angle=-50, end angle=-130, radius=0.16];
\else   
    \draw[\koala@body!50!black,thick] (1.02,1.42) arc [start angle=-50, end angle=-130, radius=0.16];
\fi
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% optional
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
% Blushed %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ifkoala@blush
    \fill[red,path fading=tikzling@blush] (0.63,1.55) circle (0.1); 
    \fill[red,path fading=tikzling@blush] (1.22,1.55) circle (0.1);
\fi
%
}
```

And here is an MWE:

```
\documentclass[border={1cm 3.14mm 1cm 3.14mm}]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzkoalas}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0.925,3) {\verb|\koala|};
 \koala 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0.925,3) {\verb|\koala[3D]|};
 \koala[3D] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0.925,3) {\verb|\koala[sleeping]|};
 \koala[sleeping] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0.925,3) {\verb|\koala[blush,3D]|};
 \koala[blush,3D] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \node[anchor=south,align=center] at (0.925,3) {\verb|\koala[sleeping,3D]|};
 \koala[sleeping,3D] 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 13):

This is just a proposal … I wanted to make this ship with some beach and some hills with forests and so on … but for now just the ship.

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.text}
\definecolor{Orange}{RGB}{255,178,70}
\definecolor{dunkel}{RGB}{201,45,4}
\definecolor{mast}{RGB}{255,132,22}
\definecolor{segel}{RGB}{255,249,203}
\definecolor{flagge}{RGB}{212,32,41}
\definecolor{gelb}{RGB}{255,199,76}
\definecolor{strand}{RGB}{254,246,174} %for beach
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \draw[xshift=-.1cm,fill=mast] (3.1,-2.1) -- (3.15,1.9) arc(-180:-360:.05) -- (3.3,-2.1) -- cycle;
        \draw[fill=mast,rotate=-10,xshift=2cm,yshift=.5cm,rounded corners=1pt] (0,0) rectangle (2,.1);
        \draw[fill=mast,rotate=-10,xshift=1.6cm,yshift=1.9cm,rounded corners=1pt] (0,0) rectangle (2.5,.1);
            \draw[fill=segel,xshift=1.6cm,yshift=1.9cm] (2.3,-.66) to[bend right=45] (2.55,-1.8) .. controls (.3,-.8) and (.4,-1.4) .. (.3,-1.5) to[bend left=45] (.5,-.34) -- cycle;
            \draw[fill=segel,xshift=1.5cm,yshift=.5cm] (.58,-.35) to[bend right=45] (.6,-1.8) .. controls (.2,-1.4) and (2,-1.5) .. (2.4,-2) to[bend left=30] (2.3,-.66) -- cycle;
                \draw[fill=Orange] (5.3,-1.2) -- (5.25,-1.7) .. controls (5.2,-2) and (5.4,-2.1) .. (5.5,-2.15) 
                %to[bend left=45] (5.5,-4);
                .. controls (5.8,-3) and (6,-3.5) .. (5.5,-4) .. controls (2.6,-4.5) and (2.7,-4.3) .. (.1,-3.98) to[bend right=5] (.05,-2) to[bend right=5] (.05,-1.6) to[bend right=5] (2,-1.8) to[bend right=5] (2.2,-2.1) -- (4.1,-2) to[bend right=45] (4.1,-1.2);
                    \draw[fill=dunkel] (0,-1.5) to[bend right=5] (2,-1.8) --+ (.3,-.3) --+ (2,-.2) arc(270:360+90:.25 and .4) --+ (1.3,0) --+ (1.3,-.1) --+ (.25,-.08) arc(90:270:-.15 and .4) --+ (-2,-.13) to[bend left=10] (1.95,-1.9) to[bend left=3] (0,-1.65);
                        \draw[fill=dunkel] (0,0) -- (.2,.05) to[bend right=7] (.3,-4) --+ (-.2,-.05) to[bend left=5] (0,0);
                    \fill[dunkel] (.7,-2.2) circle(.25);
                    \fill[gelb] (.7,-2.2) circle(.15);
                \foreach \x in {4.5,4.75,5}
                {
                    \fill[rounded corners=1pt,dunkel,xshift=\x cm,yshift=-2cm] (0,0) rectangle (.15,.5);
                }
        \draw[fill=dunkel,xshift=5cm,yshift=-1.2cm] (0,0) rectangle (.1,1);
        \node[minimum width=1cm,minimum height=.5cm,xshift=5.45cm,yshift=-1.27cm,above] (a) at (.05,1) {};
            \draw[fill=flagge] (a.south west) to[bend left=45] ($(a.south west)!.5!(a.south east)$) to[bend right=45] (a.south east) -- (a.north east) to[bend left=45] ($(a.north east)!.5!(a.north west)$) to[bend right=45] (a.north west) -- cycle;
        \path [xshift=1.35cm,yshift=.9cm,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={TeX.SX}}}] (.6,-2) .. controls (.2,-1.4) and (2,-1.5) .. (2.4,-2);
        \path [rotate=180,xshift=-4.35cm,yshift=-2.2cm,postaction={decorate,decoration={text along path,text align=center,text={|\tt|@samcarter}}}] (2.55,1.8) .. controls (2.7,.8) and (1,1.4) .. (.3,1.8);
        \begin{scope}[scale=.2,xshift=2cm,yshift=-7.85cm,rotate=-20]
            \duck[speech={\scalebox{.2}{\rotatebox{-25}{Argh!!!}}}]
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[scale=.2,xshift=13.6cm,xscale=-1,yshift=-10.3cm,rotate=-10]
            \duck[sunglasses=blue,speech={\scalebox{.2}{\rotatebox{15}{Nah.}}}]
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[scale=.2,xshift=23cm,xscale=-1,yshift=-5.85cm,rotate=-10]
            \duck[recedinghair=white,beard,speech={\scalebox{.1}{\rotatebox{15}{Follow the sun!}}}]
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[shift={(2.6,2.4)}]
            \fill[even odd rule,brown!80!black] (0,0) arc(180:360:.5) (0,0) arc(180:360:.5 and .2);
            \draw[brown!80!black,fill=white] (.5,0) circle(.5 and .2);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}[scale=.2,xshift=14.5cm,yshift=11.5cm,rotate=-10]
            \duck[hat=black!70!brown!50!blue,cape=magenta,speech={\scalebox{.15}{\rotatebox{-15}{Fly away!}}}]
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

---

**UPDATE:** This is just a little comic – feel free to complete the story!

```
\documentclass[border=5pt,tikz]{standalone} %article
\usepackage{tikzmarmots,tikzducks}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes,positioning}
\definecolor{forest}{RGB}{34,139,34}
\definecolor{aqua}{RGB}{127,255,212}
\definecolor{ground}{RGB}{239,206,163}
\definecolor{gras}{RGB}{98,174,48}
\definecolor{sky}{RGB}{135,206,235}
\definecolor{navo}{RGB}{255,222,173}
\definecolor{water}{RGB}{64,164,223}
\begin{document}
%   \resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (-.1,-6.1) rectangle (8.06,3.1);
            \draw[shorten >=-4cm,double distance=1mm] ($(0,0)!.6!(8,.5)$) --+ (.5,-.5);
            \draw[double distance=1mm] (0,0) -- (8,.5);
                \draw[double distance=1mm] (0,-6) rectangle (8,3);
            \draw[double distance=1mm] (.06,-3) -- (7.95,-3);
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (.05,.05) -- (7.95,.57) -- (7.95,2.95) -- (.05,2.95) -- cycle;
            \foreach \x in {-1.2,-1,...,10}
            \foreach \y in {.2,.4,...,10}
            {
                \fill[red] (\x,\y) circle(1pt);
            }
            \node[minimum width=2cm,fill=white,cloud,draw,inner sep=0pt,cloud puffs=20] at (4,1.6) {\LARGE\bf BANG!};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (.07,-.05) -- ([yshift=-.05cm]$(0,0)!.6!(8,.5)$) -- ([yshift=.05cm]7.95,-3) -- ([yshift=.05cm].07,-3) -- cycle;
%               \fill[orange!20] (0,-3) rectangle (10,3);
            \begin{scope}[yshift=-3cm]
%                   \fill[rounded corners=.2cm,aqua] (2,.07) rectangle (9,1);
                    \fill[bottom color=sky,top color=sky!40] (0,0) rectangle (8,3.5);
                            \fill[xshift=-1cm,gras] (0,1) -- (4,1) to[bend right=20] (0,1);
                            \fill[xshift=1cm,gras] (0,1) -- (4,1) to[bend right=30] (0,1);
                            \fill[xshift=2cm,gras] (0,1) -- (4,1) to[bend right=40] (0,1);
                            \fill[xshift=3.5cm,gras] (0,1) -- (4,1) to[bend right=25] (0,1);
                        \fill[yshift=1cm,rounded corners=.1cm,ground] (-1,.07) rectangle (8,-1);
                \marmot\coordinate (a) at (1,1.45);
                    \node at (6.5,.5) {\tiny\sl
                        \begin{tabular}{l}
                            Meanwhile in \\
                            \textsc{New Marmot} \ldots
                        \end{tabular}
                    };
                \node[text width=3.5cm,
                      fill=white,rectangle callout,
                      callout absolute pointer=(a.west),
                      draw] at (3.7,1.7) 
                      {\small I've got the magical letter \emph{\color{orange}k}. What should I do now?};
                    \node[rotate=-50,orange] at (.7,.65) {\emph{k}};
            \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip ($(.35,0)!.6!(8,.4)$) -- (7.94,.45) -- (7.94,-2.75) -- cycle;
            \foreach \x in {0,.2,...,4.4}
            {
                \draw[xshift=5cm,red,ultra thick,xshift=\x cm] (60:.5) -- (240:3.1);
            }
            \node[fill=white,star,star points=10,draw] at (7,-1) {\sl Swoosh!};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (.07,-3.05) -- (7.95,-3.05) -- (7.95,-5.93) -- (.07,-5.93) -- cycle;
                        \fill[navo,yshift=-4.4cm] ([xshift=4.25cm]0,-.4) -- ([xshift=4.25cm]0,-2) -- ([xshift=7.75cm]0,-2) -- ([xshift=7.75cm]0,-.4) arc(0:-180:1.75cm and 1.1cm) --+ (0,-2);
                    \fill[xshift=6cm,yshift=-4.8cm,navo!90!black] (0,0) circle(1.8cm and 1.1cm);
                        \draw[ultra thick,red,xshift=4.25cm,yshift=-4.5cm,navo!90!black] (0,-.4) -- (0,-2);
                        \draw[ultra thick,red,xshift=7.75cm,yshift=-4.5cm,navo!90!black] (0,-.4) -- (0,-2);
                \fill[xshift=6cm,yshift=-4.8cm,water!60] (0,0) circle(1.7cm and 1cm);
%               \begin{scope}[xshift=-3.5cm]
%                   \fill[navo!90,yshift=-4.4cm] ([xshift=4.25cm]0,-.4) -- ([xshift=4.25cm]0,-2) -- ([xshift=7.75cm]0,-2) -- ([xshift=7.75cm]0,-.4) arc(0:-180:1.75cm and 1.1cm) --+ (0,-2);
%                   \fill[xshift=6cm,yshift=-4.8cm,navo!70!brown] (0,0) circle(1.8cm and 1.1cm);
%                   \draw[ultra thick,red,xshift=4.25cm,yshift=-4.5cm,navo!70!brown] (0,-.4) -- (0,-2);
%                   \draw[ultra thick,red,xshift=7.75cm,yshift=-4.5cm,navo!70!brown] (0,-.4) -- (0,-2);
%                   \fill[xshift=6cm,yshift=-4.8cm,water!60] (0,0) circle(1.7cm and 1cm);
%               \end{scope}
%               \begin{scope}[xshift=-7cm]
%                   \fill[navo,yshift=-4.4cm] ([xshift=4.25cm]0,-.4) -- ([xshift=4.25cm]0,-2) -- ([xshift=7.75cm]0,-2) -- ([xshift=7.75cm]0,-.4) arc(0:-180:1.75cm and 1.1cm) --+ (0,-2);
%                   \fill[xshift=6cm,yshift=-4.8cm,navo!90!black] (0,0) circle(1.8cm and 1.1cm);
%                   \draw[ultra thick,red,xshift=4.25cm,yshift=-4.5cm,navo!30!brown] (0,-.4) -- (0,-2);
%                   \draw[ultra thick,red,xshift=7.75cm,yshift=-4.5cm,navo!30!brown] (0,-.4) -- (0,-2);
%                   \fill[xshift=6cm,yshift=-4.8cm,water!60] (0,0) circle(1.7cm and 1cm);
%               \end{scope}
            \begin{scope}[shift={(2,-5.75)}]
            \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
                \duck
                    \node[text width=3cm,rounded corners=4pt,fill=white,draw,rectangle callout,callout absolute pointer={([xshift=-.2cm]bill)}] at (-3,1) {Oh no, our beautiful letter \emph{\color{orange}k}, it's missing!};
                \end{scope}
                        \node at (5,2.4) {\tiny\sl
                            \begin{tabular}{l}
                                Somewhere else \\
                                in Duc\underline{\textcolor{white}{k}}\textcolor{forest}{\textit{city}} \ldots
                            \end{tabular}
                        };
                \end{scope}
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}
%}
\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Noah’s ark for the TeX menagerie!

Comment: This is gorgeous!

Comment: I wished I could upvote a second time for the comic!

Comment: I guess I know the answer: they will continue as duc and markmot. ;-) Really nice! ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Some penguins from the [`tikzpingus`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikzpingus) package, stolen straight from the documentation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpingus}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\pingu
\pingu[%
    crown 2d=pingu@bronze,
    medal=pingu@purple,
    tie,
    eye patch left=teal,
    eye patch right=orange,
    right wing wave,
    sunglasses,
    glow thick=yellow,
    xshift=2.8cm
    ]
\pingu[%
    cane left,
    right item flip,
    sign post right={Hi!},
    monocle left,
    body=red,
    xshift=6cm
    ]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pingus]