# Pictogram Pie and Bar Chart

Tags: charts

For my stats class, I am wanting to be able to make a pictogram (defined for this class as a bar graph with pictures for bars) similar to the ones below if required. A quick google and SE search gives nothing, so I figured I would ask. I have no idea where to start, so I cannot give any code. I do know how to use their normal versions in `PGFPlots` and `pgf-pie`, and if possible would like to stay within those packages.

Bar Chart Example

[image]

Pie Chart Example

[image]

Comment: Pizza with sweetcorn or pineapple? Is it for perverts? :o)

Comment: @Bernard +1, Italians totally agree with you!!!

Comment: @Bernard -- what a waste of sweetcorn!  (much better left on a cob and roasted.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton: I'd  rather favour *slow food* (‘seven hours leg of lamb’ and the like…)

Answer (score 3):

I *must* answer this!

For the second part, you could clip your pictures.

The "pizza" images used in the `\includegraphics` of my MWE are from [the cook duck of the duck pond](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/387126/101651) with different backgrounds, of course, you'll have to change them into your own images.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\tikzset{%
    mynode/.style={draw, circle, very thick, inner sep=1.5pt},
    myseparator/.style={white, line width=1mm},
}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}
        \centering
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) -- (3,0) arc (0:75:3cm) -- cycle;
            \node{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{pizzacyan}};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) -- ([shift={(75:3cm)}]0,0) arc (75:170:3cm) -- cycle;
            \node{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{pizzared}};
        \end{scope} 
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) -- ([shift={(170:3cm)}]0,0) arc (170:210:3cm) -- cycle;
            \node{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{pizzagreen}};
        \end{scope}
        \begin{scope}
            \clip (0,0) -- ([shift={(210:3cm)}]0,0) arc (210:360:3cm) -- cycle;
            \node{\includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{pizzablue}};
        \end{scope}     
        \draw[myseparator] (0,0) -- (4,0);
        \foreach \myangle in {75,170,210} {%
            \draw[myseparator] (0,0) -- ([shift={(\myangle:4cm)}]0,0);
        }       
        \foreach \myangle/\myname in
            {40/cyanslice,130/redslice,190/greenslice,290/blueslice} {%
            \node[mynode] at ([shift={(\myangle:2cm)}]0,0) (\myname) {};
        }
        \draw (cyanslice) -- ++(1.4,0) -- ++(.5,.5) node[yshift=.4cm, 
        text width=7em, anchor= north west] {{\LARGE 20\% }\\Prosciutto\\ e funghi};
        \draw (redslice) -- ++(-2,0) -- ++(-1,.5) node[yshift=.4cm, 
        text width=6em, anchor= north east, align=flush right] {{\LARGE 30\% }\\Margherita};
        \draw (greenslice) -- ++(-1.4,0) -- ++(-.5,-.5) node[yshift=.4cm, 
        text width=7em, anchor= north east, align=flush right] {{\LARGE Car\LaTeX}\\Salsiccia e \\ friarielli};
        \draw (blueslice) -- ++(2,0) -- ++(.5,-.5) node[yshift=.4cm, 
        text width=5em, anchor= north west] {{\LARGE 40\% }\\Napoletana};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption*{Preferred pizzas by Italians\\ (no pineapple one on the rankings)}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

P.S. = The percentages are random.

Comment: -1 No Hawaiian Pizza? What do the Italians know about pizza?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Italians : pizzas = DEK : TeX

Answer (score 2):

As a quick hack for the first chart, you could

- borrow the `fill stretch image` option from `tcolorbox`
- add every bar as an individual plot

---

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}
\usepackage[skins]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ybar]
\addplot [fill stretch image=example-image-b] coordinates {(1,1)};
\addplot [fill stretch image=example-image-b] coordinates {(2,3)};
\addplot [fill stretch image=example-image-b] coordinates {(3,2)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Another hack for the bar plot drawn in tikz, so you need to draw the tick marks manually. The height of the bar is given in percentage. (Things can be more automated, like counting the number of bars.)

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
  \newcommand\BarHeight{4}% Max height of bar picture
  \newcommand\BarWidth{1}% Width of bar picture
  \newcommand\Xdist{0.2}% Space between bars
  \newcommand\NumberBars{5}
  \draw[->] (0,0)--(0,\BarHeight cm+0.5 cm);
  \pgfmathparse{\NumberBars*(\BarWidth+\Xdist)+\Xdist+0.2}\edef\lengthxaxis{\pgfmathresult}
  \draw[->] (0,0)--(\lengthxaxis,0);
  \foreach \Num/\Label [count=\ind from 0] in {%
    80/ABC,
    60/CBS,
    40/FOX,
    100/NBC,
    70/ETC}{%
    \pgfmathparse{\Num/100*\BarHeight}\edef\Heightofbar{\pgfmathresult}
    \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west,label=-90:\small\textsf{\Label}] at 
    (\ind*\BarWidth+\ind*\Xdist+\Xdist,0){%
      \includegraphics[width=\BarWidth cm, height=\Heightofbar cm]{example-image}};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]