# @string issues with current Biblatex/Biber: how can I stop my authors undergoing existence failures?

Tags: biblatex, biber, strings

My bibliography set-up relies extensively on BibTeX strings. Until very recently - just now, essentially - this worked fine. Now, however, it works hardly at all.

Here's a minimal example. I'm not entirely sure what the crucial elements are, but if I combine `abbrv2.bib` with `abbrv3.bib`, the problem disappears.

```
\begin{filecontents}{abbrv2.bib}
%:punctuation - but use Biblatex macros where possible!
@string{/                               =   {\addslash }}
@string{name-some   = {Name, Some}}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{abbrv3.bib}
@string{great-stuff = {Great } # / # { Stuff}}
\end{filecontents}


\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{name-fascinate,
  author  = name-some,
  journal = great-stuff,
  pages   = {34--67},
  year    = 1765,
  volume  = 3,
  number  = 2,
  title   = {Fascinating Finds}}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{abbrv2, abbrv3, \jobname}
\begin{document}

\autocite{name-fascinate}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Note the lack of an author in the bibliography entry.

[image: erroneous output]

My real document has no authors, journals, publishers, addresses, joining words ....

What is the cause? (Please don't say this is a new feature!) How can I avoid the problem (Can I avoid the problem?) without reverting to BibTeX? Reverting to BibTeX would be a great deal of work, but probably significantly less than doing away with the use of `@string`.

Comment: cfr, I can reproduce the problem. I've tried it with `addbibresource` (`bibliography` is deprecated), but to no avail. I can't fix it, but I noticed the result depends on the order in which the bib files are loaded. In particular, if I load it "abbrv2.bib", "abbrv3.bib", "\jobname.bib", biber issues a warning "undefined macro "name-some"". So it appears the strings are captured from the immediately previous file ("great stuff" captures the slash), but not if loaded "in chain". Thus, if you merge your abbrv files it works. I know it doesn't help much, but that's what I could find out so far.

Comment: @gusbrs Thanks for investigating. I think it may be linked to a bug report concerning disappearing months. If so, it is supposed to be fixed in the development version. However, I can't find the binaries on sourceforge for this version - only the source and the matching (I think) Biblatex. Merging the files isn't really an option for me in my actual use case, sadly :(.

Comment: Usually, I'd just revert to TL2016. But I'm on a new machine, so I don't have that option :(.

Comment: Let's see what others more knowledgeable have to say. Curiously, `@string`, as far as I searched, is not documented in biblatex's manual. There's `xdata` though...

Comment: Looks like a clear bug to me, but it is not resolved in the development version and I added a issue to the bug tracker https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/204. If you are in pressing need I can tell you how to fall back to an older biblatex/biber combo. Unrelated: (advertisement ;-)): Thinking of you we put some welsh elements in our video: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/405060/2388

Comment: The issue should be resolved with the latest biber version.

Comment: @gusbrs `@string` is from BibTeX and has been recognised in the `.bib` format for ... well, ever since I've been using it. Suddenly not supporting it would be a pretty major non-backwards-compatible change.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for investigating & reporting. May I ask, where are you downloading the latest versions from? Do I need to build the sources? That's what I got trying to download the development version from sourceforge, but I was hoping to find a binary.

Comment: The biber binaries are here https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex-biber/files/biblatex-biber/, the biblatex.tds https://sourceforge.net/projects/biblatex/files/?source=navbar. I normally rename the biber.exe to biberdev.exe and put the biblatex development files in a texmf tree of their own so that they can be easily enabled and disabled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a temporary Biber issue. It was solved in version 2.10 of Biber. See https://github.com/plk/biber/issues/204